# Is it possible to optimize internet connection for video streaming

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu, download, speed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I throttle the bandwidth consumed by Windows Automatic Updates?](https://superuser.com/questions/84723/how-can-i-throttle-the-bandwidth-consumed-by-windows-automatic-updates)

I'm always watching anime online. I want to know if it is possible to allot more bandwidth on online streaming than in downloading. Because I've notice in ubuntu that it prioritize the downloads. And XP prioritize the browsing. Because I get higher download rates in ubuntu than in xp. 
Is there any software that I can use in order to modify what the os prioritizes.

Comment: Same principle, different application being limited: http://superuser.com/questions/84723/how-can-i-throttle-the-bandwidth-consumed-by-windows-automatic-updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Traffic Shaper XP](http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html)** is a free bandwidth limiter for Windows 2000, XP and 2003 Server. It combines high performance traffic shaping with the ease of use and flexibility to keep your network free of congestion.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [SG TCP Optimizer](http://www.speedguide.net/downloads.php) to tweak settings.  It did help the network speed overall, but I can't say it made a quantum leap of a difference.

For websites that seem to stream slow, I've ended up increasing the buffer size so I would get larger segments without interruption, even if they took longer to accumulate.

I almost wonder if it the problem may be the player used.  Maybe the Ubuntu play can better handle out of order/dropped packets.