# Stopping all automatic updates Windows 10

Tags: windows-update, windows-10

We've upgraded some machines to Windows 10 and realized there were some updates which updated as required. However, I realized there was no option available to stop the download similar to that on Windows 7 and 8.1. The only way I could stop the download was to stop the *Windows Update* service.

My question is does anyone know of a way to stop auto updates or is stopping the service is the only solution?

Comment: If you have Windows 10 Home then this cannot be done.  If you have Windows 10 Professional you can defer updates up to 8 months.  if you have Windows 10 Enterprise you can defer updates provide you indicated the LSTB you wish to use.  There is a tool which you can download that will allow you to defer individual updates if they cause a problem.  [This question has already been asked several times now.](http://superuser.com/questions/923186/how-can-i-defer-updates-in-windows-10-home).

Comment: Additionally, at the end of the day, in order to receive future security updates your system must have all required updates even if you are running Windows 10 Professional.  [KB3073930](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930) is the tool you want if you want to hide/defer individual updates.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand that security updates will be required etc but sometimes you just want to pause them and start them later on. We're running pro version. Would you happen to know where I can get the tool which you mentioned in your comment?

Comment: I already provided a link twice.  Once in a comment to the answer of the linked question and once in my comment to this very question.  If you are unable to select which updates you wish to update, then you have not enabled something, and I am far to tired to look for that option for you.

Comment: @Ramhound Right, I didn't realise the second link.. Thanks for the help

Comment: You shouldn't need that tool though if you are actually running Windows 10 Professional though.

Comment: [Here is some more information](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/4881/windows-10-and-automatic-updates)

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your help I found the option settings and posted the answer

Comment: Stopping and deferring is 2 different things.

Comment: Please note that all of the answers here only cover updates from Windows Update, but it's not clear whether the question is meant to cover that.  Windows 10 appears to have two other built-in methods of updating: device driver updates are controlled separately (System &rarr; Advanced system settings &rarr; Hardware &rarr; Device Installation Settings seems to cover this) and automatic updating of Store apps is controlled via the Store (I think this will also stop Candy Crush Soda Saga, for example, from being installed automatically).

Comment: All these answers are overly complex and doesnt fully prevent updating of the system. Also I do not want to install 3rd party software to just disable updates. It's a security risk right there. My solution works: https://superuser.com/questions/1365960/its-2018-october-what-is-the-best-way-to-disable-windows-10-win10-annoying-a?noredirect=1#comment2054244_1365960 as of 2018 October.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

if you have the Pro Edition, [open group policy editor (gpedit.msc)](http://www.howtogeek.com/224471/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-downloading-updates/) search for the `Configure automatic updates` entry, located at:

```
computer configuration → administrative templates → windows components → windows update
```

[image]

and select `Notify for download and notify for install`.

When Windows detects new updates [it shows a toast notification](http://www.askvg.com/forcing-windows-10-to-always-notify-before-downloading-updates/).

[image]

You can also use the troubleshooter from [Update KB3073930](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930) to disable some problematic updates, so that they are not installed again.

[image]

[image]

This is the official way from Microsoft to prevent setup of unwanted updates and drivers.

But there is a 3rd party tool called [Windows Update MiniTool](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/Windows_update_minitool.html) which allows to select which updates can be installed and allows to block updates like you could in former Windows versions.

[image]

> An alternative to the standard Windows Update What you can do: 
> • Check
> for updates 
>  • Download updates
>  • Installing Updates
>  •
> Deleting installed updates
>  • **Hiding unwanted updates**
>  • Get
> direct links to the *.cab / *.Exe / *.Psf update files
>  • View update
> history
>  • **Configure Automatic Updates**
>  • This tool is like the
> external powershell module PSWindowsUpdate, but much more advanced and
> user-friendly features
>  • The tool relies and use same WU
> infrastructure, all downloading are through WU it's not a
> downloader

The user [slavanap](https://superuser.com/users/303819/slavanap) posted a 2nd tool [in a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10/948069#comment1650998_948069) which allows you to selectively install updates. It is called [Windows10 Manual Update and is available on github](https://github.com/slavanap/Windows10ManualUpdate):

[image].

In the [Windows 10 creators Update, there is an option](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2017/01/how-to-pause-your-windows-10-updates.html) to stop Windows Updates for 35 days:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

under Settings App where the Windows Update options are.

Comment: From the kb307390 link "How to temporarily prevent a Windows or driver update from reinstalling in Windows 10" this does not permanently block the update from installing

Comment: It does however prevent it for a while.

Comment: What if you have the Home edition?

Comment: @ColonelPanic try to set the value **AUOptions** under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU** to **2**. Does this work?

Comment: I used the Group Policy Editor method and it appears to have stopped Windows Update (I have been using this configuration for around 6 months), although I don't just get a "toast notification" as shown above, sometimes I get a dialog in the middle of the screen which doesn't have any kind of close/cancel button, and when I hit the button it opens up the Windows Update tool.  However, I can close that to prevent updates from being installed.

Comment: @doshea I have no idea which issue you have. I still get the toast notification

Comment: I don't think that MiniTool is open source. Please refer this open source the simplest solution how to perform Windows 10 Update maintenance similar to pervious Windows versions https://github.com/slavanap/Windows10ManualUpdate

Comment: @magicandre1981 Creator Update allows an Ethernet connection to be marked as a metered connection. And you know, automatic update does not work over metered connections.

Comment: @FleetCommand this is a crappy hack. Use the offered tools to search for updates. And don't don't sabotage the topic by adding softpedia crap links.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sabotage? That is not exactly a "thank you" for repairing a dead and dead-end link.

Comment: -1 not because it's your fault, but because your answer is now out of date. Windows now turns Windows Update back on even after all the classic workarounds.

Comment: @Mehrdad it still works, you simply can't use WindowsUpdateMiniTool correctly ‍♂️ I've excluded kb4134661 with WindowsUpdateMiniTool and I'm still not updated to 1803 from 1709. Everything works fine. Delete your account and troll somewhere else

Comment: @magicandre1981 with all due respect, I have one problem with your answer, it emphasises on deferring updates rather than stalling them

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith the answer still works. I still use Windows Update MiniTool in 1903 home edition without any issues.

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks for answering. i have retracted my comment. i will try out minitool! and report back (sry for wasting your time... i'm really thankful for your reply and showing that you care!). users like you make stack network amazing :).

Comment: @magicandre1981 MiniTool is a third-party software. Do you trust MiniTool? If yes, why?

Comment: @magicandre1981 i looked a little bit into MiniTool author/programmer. found a [reddit that says it works](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/9q2neb/windows_update_minitool_wumt_is_it_safe_and_does/). found a link to [winguru where an article about it writes "As far as I can tell, it involves an un-named Russian translator who maintains and handles the code base on behalf of an even more shadowy principal developer"](https://win10.guru/toolkit-item-windows-update-minitool-wumt/).

Comment: The MiniTool might still work. But development has stopped and so an opensource alternative is available called: [article talking about MiniTool and WuMgr](https://piunikaweb.com/2018/09/20/windows-update-manager-wumgr-windows-10/) at [WuMgr at Github](https://github.com/DavidXanatos/wumgr/).

Comment: I also know the other tool, as long as Mini Tool works I'll use it as it uses WindowsUpdate API.

Comment: I use minitool on all my W7-W10 machines, it just works and is safe, it is just a front end for the built in windows update, nothing nefarious about it. No virus detected either. Its the true solution to controlling Windows updates on W10.

Comment: seems to be they have removed `notify to download and notify for install` option, only `notify for download and auto-install` left on 1909. Dunno if they are the same

Comment: @Moab, are you security expert to say it's safe? Just need to know for sure if it's safe.

Comment: @BohdanKuts I wouldn't have said it if it wasn't.

Comment: Since the original author has pulled his blog an wumt, here is the continued project>>>>>https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/wumt_wrapper_script.html

Comment: The Group Policy Editor method does not work anymore. I had it configured: `7 - Auto download, notify to install, notify to restart`, but despite it updates are installed silently and windows restarts without my permission :(

Comment: @EugeneMala it works for all my systems (Build 19043, 18363) in VMs and on real devices. I prefer only to notify, bot to download.

Answer (score 11):

One of the most controversial aspect about  Windows 10 is Microsoft’s decision to make updates obligatory. If you have Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise or Education editions you can defer updates, *but you can’t reject them outright*.

If you’re unhappy with Microsoft forcefully installing updates on your system without your say, you can **block this function** using the **[W10Privacy](https://www.winprivacy.de/english-home/)**.

> If you haven’t heard of this program before it’s well worth checking
> out as the software gives you control over Windows 10’s many privacy
> functions, allowing you to prevent the OS snooping on what you do.
> Options are color coded so you can see at a glance whether something
> is safe to change/disable or not.

> In [**W10Privacy 2**](https://www.winprivacy.de/english-home/), you can now set the program to disable Windows 10’s
> own update mechanism and replace it with its own. Users can choose
> which updates to install, and which to ignore. This isn't something
> everyone should do, but you can easily reverse the steps should you
> need to.

**Before you can use this function, you need to download some additional components. Follow these steps:**

- Download [**W10Privacy 2**](http://www.winprivacy.de/english-home/) and unzip it to a folder on your hard drive.
- Download **PsExec** (part of [**PsTools** package](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools)) and copy it into the W10Privacy folder.
- Download the **Windows Update PowerShell Module** from [Technet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc/view/Discussions#content), and unzip it to a subfolder in the W10Privacy folder.
- Right-click `W10Privacy.exe` and choose Run as administrator from the context menu. Choose to make a system restore point. It’s also worth making a full system backup (just in case).
- Go to Extras > Windows Updates to manage the options.
  There are six different check boxes. None are enabled by default. They are:
- **PSWindows Update module** exists (must be provided previously by user
  to the W10Privacy folder).
- **PsExec.exe** in W10Privacy folder (must be provided by user).
  W10Privacy adaption of the PSWindows-Update Module.
- Configure fake WSUS server.
- W10Privacy is located in a path/folder without spaces. Do not
  consider drivers in Update Search.
- Assuming you want to manage updates manually, check the first five
  options. The sixth option lets you decide whether to list drivers
  alongside updates. This is up to you.
- Click Set changed settings then click the Start checking for updates
  button and you’ll be shown any new updates that have yet to be
  installed and can choose what action to take.

[image: Screenshot]

Once you’re in charge of your updates, run the software regularly and check to make sure you don’t miss any important updates;

[image]

**Update**

It appears the link for the Windows Update PowerShell Module is dead, however you can still install install the module in any of the following ways:

1. You can use [PowerShellGet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-7.2) to install using this command:

   `Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate`

or you can

2. Use a mirror [link form Majorgeeks](https://m.majorgeeks.com/files/details/windows_update_powershell_module.html)

Credits:

1. [How to get total control over Windows 10's automatic updates](http://betanews.com/2016/02/22/control-windows-10-updates/)

Comment: Best solution, since it entirely prevents Windows from seeing updates at all.

Comment: oh no.. Why there is no single command. Somebody give me door this window is high to walk around.

Comment: seems a little bit of overkill to bring up own WSUS server just to disable it

Comment: @Snow I have updated the links

Comment: W10Privacy and W10Privacy 2 are all entirely **close-source** while you give them access to the absolute most crucial and foundational settings of your system. Installing this gives it basically full administrative access to your computer and thus the right to read and write every single file in your system, and do any possible kind of mess in it if the developer ever wants to. **Be aware of this**...

Answer (score 7):

**For Windows 10 Home Users**

Try the following method from [Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-prevent-windows-10-rebooting-after-installing-updates).  Basically, you will disable the reboot service, not the update service.  You can then reboot whenever you want.  Please note, you need administrator privileges, but I assume you already have it since you are using Windows Home edition.

1. From a Windows explorer window, rename the file: `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot` (assuming your `%windir%` is `C:\`) to Reboot.old.  *Note, you will be asked for administrator access here.*
2. Create a directory named `Reboot` in `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\`.  This will prevent windows from recreating a file with the same name. *Note, you will be asked for administrator access here.*
3. Reboot the machine.  This will reset all of the services, and prevent the reboot service from starting.

Please note, this is not promoted by Microsoft.  But then again, neither is controlling you own boot schedule, so take that MS!  Seriously, if you don't know what you are doing understand the risks you are taking by following any directions off the Internet.  This is certainly simple enough that an understanding of Windows 95 would help explain what is happening here.

Comment: Has anyone used this method and can attest this is safe in the long term ? My fears are basically that the update system will trigger someday and do everything it needs up until the reboot but then fail because of this and you won't be able to boot your system up again because rebooting it forcefully will not make windows understand it was currently in an update phase and that it has to do the steps that are needed after the restart.

Answer (score 6):

With the help of @Ramhound I have managed to figure out how to stop automatic updates on windows 10.

Please note this applies to **Windows 10 Pro** as it's the version I am running.

To stop the autmatic updates you can do the following:

1. Open Settings
2. Click on Update & security
3. Click on `Advanced options` 
   [image]
4. Ensure `Defer upgrades` option is checked
   [image]
5. Close down the settings window and that's it you're done!

**Update**

As mentioned in the comments by @Vinayak the defer option is now available for home users too. Further information [here](https://superuser.com/a/968658/474879)

Comment: While your in there looking , could you see if there is a windows update service that can just be disabled in services. Wuauserv or wuaueng.dll or something?  for those who might use a different method?

Comment: @Psycogeek `Wuauserv` service is there and can be stopped/disabled. This is how I originally stopped the updates

Comment: Much of the web is making it sound as if the world will stop turning , if the windows 10  updates are stopped :-)   and how the button does not  exist in some  editions.  I am assuming you did not have any trouble with that?  the dream police did not invade your nightmares ,   the OS did not collapse into a ball, and no pets were harmed in the in the process :-)  I think this Q&A here is well done and can be re-used for similar W10 update control questions .

Comment: @Psycogeek LOL Love the comment.. I did not have any problem by stoping the service.

Comment: Note that Microsoft caved in and now **Defer upgrades** [is available for Windows 10 Home users as well](http://superuser.com/a/968658/167187).

Comment: **defer** stops the upgrade to a newer Version like 1511 (November 2015 Update) or 1607 (anniversary update in July 2016) and keeps you getting automatic updates for the older version.

Comment: Windows 10 Pro version 1709 does not show a "Defer upgrades" option there.

Comment: @Izzy "Defer" is not the same verb as "stop", do you realize that ? Plus, this only defers feature updates, not fixes for your current version. So basically, you still haven't changed anything with this about windows making you lose a session by automatically rebooting for an update. **This is no solution to the question at all**.

Answer (score 6):

**The state of Windows Update - beginning 2019**

Microsoft has been taking great pains to make Windows Updates inevitable,
which is why the traditional methods don't work anymore or only work
for a limited time.

Microsoft has been adding system services that cannot be disabled, whose purpose is to update Windows.

Chief among these is the
[Update Orchestrator Service](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/update-orchestrator-service-in-windows-10),
tasked with downloading, installing, and verifying the updates.
If stopped, the computer can no longer download and install the updates,
which is why it can only be disabled for the current session and will be
re-enabled on the next reboot.

The service that is charged with making Windows Update unstoppable is the new
[Windows Update Medic Service](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-update-medic-service),
tasked with keeping Windows Update functioning.
It is this service that undoes all the traditional methods for blocking
Windows Update, so that periodically and unexpectedly, one will find out that
the Windows Update settings have been reset to their original values and that
Windows has gone back to forcing updates upon the user.

The Windows Update Medic Service itself cannot be disabled at all.
Any attempt to do so will end with the message "Access is Denied".

Nevertheless, there exists a third-party product that can block
Windows Update:
[Windows Update Blocker](https://www.sordum.org/9470/windows-update-blocker-v1-1/).
This free product is portable and can disable/enable Windows Update with one click.
In fact, it can also block any other unblockable Windows service.
It is reported as still working in 2018.

Using a third-party product may, in the long run, be surer than relying upon
Windows semi-documented features which may change without notice.
Some more free products may be found in
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1393102/8672)
of mine, which use the Windows API that allows any program to veto an
impending shutdown.

Answer (score 4):

[image: windows_update_toggle]
Massive rework of previous batch files [toggle suite](https://git.io/vx2et) into single script with best practices blocking!
[Watch it in action](https://youtu.be/_jEzgBk0_QA)

**Desktop right-click context menu dynamic UI with toggles for everything!**
*Toggle all blocks on/off, Renew (from pastebin) or uninstall script options*

**Hide / Unhide / Install update lists with counter!**
*Lists are automatically updated whenever Windows would nag you via MusNotification!*

**Independently block Build upgrades, Automatic Installs, Downloads, Service**
*IFEO safe blocking with no destructive changes of ownership, deleting files or removing tasks*

**Focus set on Defender updates working independently**
*Toggling off windows mayhem automatic updates will not sacrifice built-in protection layer,*
*unlike any other -DIY- updates "management"*

[**windows_update_toggle.bat**](https://pastebin.com/gNsLEWJe)

```
@set @version=10.0 /* &title Windows Update Toggle
@echo off &set "verbose="
echo.
echo      ---------------------------------------------------------------------
echo     :                  Windows Update Toggle v10.0 final                  :
echo     :---------------------------------------------------------------------:
echo     :      Block/Enable Upgrades, Installs, Downloads(!), Service(!)      :
echo     :         Disable/Enable Reporting, Speech, SearchUI, Defender        :
echo     :        Hide/Unhide/Apply update lists with count and max size       :
echo     :       Preset for Defender updates and Store downloads working       :
echo     :                                                                     :
echo     :     Toggle from the comfort of Desktop right-click context menu     :
echo      ---------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
:: AveYo, 2018-05-13

if %1.==. timeout /t 10 &call wscript /e:JScript "%~f0" runas setup &exit/b &rem : no arguments, run setup elevated
if %1.==shift. shift &shift &rem : if loaded by WScript, shift args to prevent loop and restore %0
if %1.==. echo ERROR! &timeout /t 5 &exit/b : must have at least one arg

:: Setup executable blocking via ifeo
set notifier=EOSNotify MusNotification
set upgrader=Windows10UpgraderApp Windows10Upgrade WindowsUpdateBox SetupHost setupprep
set installer=wuauclt
set reporter=wermgr wsqmcons DiagTrackRunner DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Service CompatTelRunner
set speecher=SpeechRuntime SpeechModelDownload
set searcher=SearchUI

set "exe=%notifier% %upgrader% %installer% %reporter%"
set "noop=%SystemRoot%\system32\systray.exe"
set "ifeo=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options"
set "menu=HKCR\DesktopBackground\shell\WUT"
set "f0=%SystemRoot%\windows_update_toggle.bat"
set "task=wscript.exe /e:JScript \"%f0%\" schtasks WUT"
set "DefMUS={MicrosoftUpdateServer|MMPC|InternalDefinitionUpdateServer}"
set "DefMMPC={MMPC|MicrosoftUpdateServer|InternalDefinitionUpdateServer}"
set ".=>nul 2>nul"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=1234567890" %%# in ('shutdown /?^|findstr /bc:"E"') do set "[T]=%%#" &rem : cosmetic usage in menus
if defined verbose (echo on &set ".=" &set "window=") else set "window=hide"
call :%~1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 &rem : launch secondary functions below dinamically, passing next args
echo.
echo Done! Use the Desktop right-click context menu to toggle, renew or uninstall
if "%~1"=="setup" (pause) else if defined verbose timeout /t 5
exit/b : End of main script, functions below

:refresh context menu
echo %0 %*
call :reg_query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WUT.bat" NoBlock noblock
if "%noblock%"=="Enable" exit/b
call :reg_query "%menu%0pending" MUIVerb pending
if defined pending exit/b
for %%# in ("1hide" "2unhide" "3apply") do reg delete "%menu%%%~#" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%0pending" /v MUIVerb /d "Pending.." /f %.%
reg add "%menu%0pending" /v SubCommands /d "" /f %.%
call :reg_query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WUT.bat" NoRefresh norefresh
if "%norefresh%"=="Disable" start "WUT" wscript /e:JScript "%f0%" WUTRefresh
call :status SetupHost
reg add "%menu%\shell\3Upgrades"   /v MUIVerb /d "Upgrades %[T]% [setuphost]    %toggle%" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\3Upgrades\command" /ve /d "%task%\upgrades" /f %.%
call :status wuauclt
reg add "%menu%\shell\4Installs"   /v MUIVerb /d "Installs %[T]% [wuauclt]    %toggle%" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\4Installs\command" /ve /d "%task%\installs" /f %.%
for /f "tokens=3" %%# in ('sc qc TrustedInstaller ^| find /I "WUTblocked"') do set "blocked=%%#"
if /i "%blocked%"=="[WUTblocked]" (set "toggle=blocked") else set "toggle=enabled"
reg add "%menu%\shell\5Downloads"  /v MUIVerb /d "Downloads ( ! ) %[T]% [trustedinstaller]    %toggle%" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\5Downloads\command" /ve /d "%task%\downloads" /f %.%
for /f "tokens=3" %%# in ('sc qc wuauserv ^| find /I "WUTblocked"') do set "blocked=%%#"
if /i "%blocked%"=="rpcss[WUTblocked]" (set "toggle=blocked") else set "toggle=enabled"
reg add "%menu%\shell\6Service"    /v MUIVerb /d "Service ( ! ) %[T]% [wuauserv]    %toggle%" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\6Service\command" /ve /d "%task%\service" /f %.%
call :status wermgr
reg add "%menu%\shell\81Report"    /v MUIVerb /d "Report    %[T]% %toggle%" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\81Report\command" /ve /d "%task%\report" /f %.%
call :status SpeechRuntime
reg add "%menu%\shell\82Speech"    /v MUIVerb /d "Speech    %[T]% %toggle%" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\82Speech\command" /ve /d "%task%\speech" /f %.%
call :status SearchUI
reg add "%menu%\shell\83Search"    /v MUIVerb /d "SearchUI  %[T]% %toggle%" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\83Search\command" /ve /d "%task%\search" /f %.%
set "defstatus=if((Get-MpPreference).DisableRealtimeMonitoring){write-host stopped}else{write-host enabled}"
for /f "delims=" %%# in ('call powershell.exe -c "%defstatus%;"') do set "toggle=%%#"
reg add "%menu%\shell\84Defender"  /v MUIVerb /d "Defender  %[T]% %toggle%" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\84Defender\command" /ve /d "%task%\defender" /f %.%
if "%norefresh%"=="Enable" reg delete "%menu%0pending" /f %.%
exit/b

:toggle WUT
echo %0 %*
call :reg_query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WUT.bat" NoBlock noblock
if "%noblock%"=="Disable" (set "toggle=Enable") else set "toggle=Disable"
for %%# in (NoBlock NoRefresh) do reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WUT.bat" /v %%# /d "%toggle%" /f %.%
:: Generate WUT main context menu
for %%# in ("" "0pending" "1hide" "2unhide" "3apply") do reg delete "%menu%%%~#" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%" /v MUIVerb /d "Windows Update Toggle" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%" /v Icon /d "appwiz.cpl,5" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%" /v SubCommands /d "" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\9Setup" /v MUIVerb /d "windows_update_toggle.bat v10.0" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\9Setup" /v SubCommands /d "" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\9Setup\shell\1Toggle" /v MUIVerb /d "%toggle%" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\9Setup\shell\2Renew"  /v MUIVerb /d "Renew" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\9Setup\shell\3Remove" /v MUIVerb /d "Remove" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\9Setup\shell\1Toggle\command" /ve /d "%task%\toggle" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\9Setup\shell\2Renew\command"  /ve /d "%task%\renew" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\9Setup\shell\3Remove\command" /ve /d "%task%\remove" /f %.%
if "%toggle%"=="Disable" (
 reg add "%menu%\shell\1Refresh" /v MUIVerb /d "Refresh" /f %.%
 reg add "%menu%\shell\1Refresh\command" /ve /d "%task%\refresh" /f %.%
 reg add "%menu%\shell\2Lists" /v MUIVerb /d "Hide / Unhide / Apply %[T]% enabled" /f %.%
 reg add "%menu%\shell\2Lists\command" /ve /d "%task%\lists" /f %.%
 reg add "%menu%\shell\7Repair"     /v MUIVerb /d "Troubleshooter" /f %.%
 reg add "%menu%\shell\7Repair\command" /ve /d "%task%\repair" /f %.%
)
:: Disabling automatic updates hinders Defender, so get definitions from MMPC first
if "%toggle%"=="Enable" ( set "DefSig=%DefMUS%" ) else set "DefSig=%DefMMPC%"
start "WUT:MpPref" wscript /e:JScript "%~f0" cmd "powershell.exe -c `Set-MpPreference -SignatureFallbackOrder %DefSig%;`"
:: Default services
sc config wuauserv type= share depend= rpcss %.%
sc config TrustedInstaller type= own depend= / %.%
:: Toggle ifeo exe blocking
for %%# in (%exe% %speech% %search%) do reg delete "%ifeo%\%%#.exe" /f %.%
if "%toggle%"=="Enable" exit/b WUT disabled, so skip the code below
for %%# in (%exe%) do reg add "%ifeo%\%%#.exe" /v Debugger /d "%noop%" /f %.% &taskkill /im "%%#.exe" /t /f %.%
:: WUTRefresh hijacking
for %%# in (MusNotification EOSNotify) do reg add "%ifeo%\%%#.exe" /v Debugger /d "%SystemRoot%\WUTRefresh.bat" /f %.%
call :refresh menu
exit/b

:hide update
echo %0 %*
call :reg_query "%menu%1hide\shell\%~1" MUIVerb updatefound
echo -%updatefound%
if not defined updatefound exit/b
call wscript /e:JScript "%f0%" hide "%updatefound%"
exit/b

:unhide update
echo %0 %*
call :reg_query "%menu%2unhide\shell\%~1" MUIVerb updatefound
echo -%updatefound%
if not defined updatefound exit/b
call wscript /e:JScript "%f0%" unhide "%updatefound%"
exit/b

:apply update
echo %0 %*
call :reg_query "%menu%3apply\shell\%~1" MUIVerb updatefound
echo -%updatefound%
if not defined updatefound exit/b
:: Temporarily unblock downloads and installs
call :reg_query "%ifeo%\wuauclt.exe" Debugger installs_blocked
for /f "tokens=3" %%# in ('sc qc TrustedInstaller ^| find /I "WUTblocked"') do set "downloads_blocked=%%#"
call wscript /e:JScript "%f0%" apply "%updatefound%"
:: Restore block
if defined installs_blocked reg add "%ifeo%\wuauclt.exe" /v Debugger /d "%noop%" /f %.% &taskkill /im "wuauclt.exe" /t /f %.%
if defined downloads_blocked sc config TrustedInstaller type= own depend= [WUTblocked] %.%
exit/b

:lists
echo %0 %*
call :reg_query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WUT.bat" NoRefresh norefresh
if "%norefresh%"=="Disable" ( set "norefresh=Enable" &set "toggle=disabled") else set "norefresh=Disable" &set "toggle=enabled"
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WUT.bat" /v NoRefresh /d "%norefresh%" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\2Lists" /v MUIVerb /d "Hide / Unhide / Apply %[T]% %toggle%" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\1Refresh" /v MUIVerb /d "Refresh" /f %.%
reg add "%menu%\shell\1Refresh\command" /ve /d "%task%\refresh" /f %.%
if "%norefresh%"=="Enable" (
 reg delete "%menu%0pending" /f %.% &reg delete "%menu%1hide" /f %.% &reg delete "%menu%2unhide" /f %.%
 reg delete "%menu%3apply" /f %.% &reg delete "%menu%\shell\1Refresh" /f %.%
)
call :refresh lists
exit/b

:upgrades
echo %0 %*
call :flip SetupHost
reg add "%menu%\shell\3Upgrades"   /v MUIVerb /d "Upgrades %[T]% [setuphost]    %toggle%" /f %.%
for %%# in (%upgrader%) do if defined block (
 reg delete "%ifeo%\%%#.exe" /f %.%
) else (
 reg add "%ifeo%\%%#.exe" /v Debugger /d "%noop%" /f %.% &taskkill /im "%%#.exe" /t /f %.%
)
exit/b

:installs
echo %0 %*
call :flip wuauclt
reg add "%menu%\shell\4Installs"   /v MUIVerb /d "Installs %[T]% [wuauclt]    %toggle%" /f %.%
for %%# in (%installer%) do if defined block (
 do reg delete "%ifeo%\%%#.exe" /f %.% &start "wt" wscript /e:JScript "%f0%" WUTRefresh
) else (
 reg add "%ifeo%\%%#.exe" /v Debugger /d "%SystemRoot%\WUTRefresh.bat" /f %.% &taskkill /im "%%#.exe" /t /f %.%
)
exit/b

:downloads
echo %0 %*
call :reg_query "%menu%3apply" MUIVerb pending
set "reboot=%pending:reboot=%"
if defined pending if "%pending%"=="%reboot%" set "pending="
if defined pending (
 sc config TrustedInstaller type= own depend= / %.%
 reg add "%menu%\shell\5Downloads" /v MUIVerb /d "Downloads ( ! ) %[T]% [trustedinstaller]    reboot?" /f %.%
 exit/b
)
for /f "tokens=3" %%# in ('sc qc TrustedInstaller ^| find /I "WUTblocked"') do set "blocked=%%#"
if /i "%blocked%"=="[WUTblocked]" (set "blocked=/") else set "blocked=[WUTblocked]"
net stop TrustedInstaller /y %.%
for /f "tokens=3" %%# in ('sc queryex TrustedInstaller ^| find /i "PID"') do set "pid=%#"
if not "%pid%"=="0" taskkill /pid %pid% /f %.%
sc config TrustedInstaller type= own depend= %blocked% %.%
tasklist /svc | find /i "TrustedInstaller" %.%
if errorlevel 1 net start TrustedInstaller /y %.%
if errorlevel 1 (set "toggle=blocked") else set "toggle=enabled"
reg add "%menu%\shell\5Downloads" /v MUIVerb /d "Downloads ( ! ) %[T]% [trustedinstaller]    %toggle%" /f %.%
if "%toggle%"=="enabled" start "WUT" wscript /e:JScript "%f0%" WUTRefresh
exit/b

:service
echo %0 %*
for /f "tokens=3" %%# in ('sc qc wuauserv ^| find /I "WUTblocked"') do set "blocked=%%#"
if /i "%blocked%"=="rpcss[WUTblocked]" (set "blocked=rpcss") else set "blocked=rpcss[WUTblocked]"
net stop wuauserv /y %.%
for /f "tokens=3" %%# in ('sc queryex wuauserv ^| find /i "PID"') do set "pid=%#"
if not "%pid%"=="0" taskkill /pid %pid% /f %.%
sc config wuauserv type= share depend= %blocked% %.%
tasklist /svc | find /i "wuauserv" %.%
if errorlevel 1 net start wuauserv /y %.%
if errorlevel 1 (set "toggle=blocked") else set "toggle=enabled"
reg add "%menu%\shell\6Service" /v MUIVerb /d "Service ( ! ) %[T]% [wuauserv]    %toggle%" /f %.%
if "%toggle%"=="enabled" start "WUT" wscript /e:JScript "%f0%" WUTRefresh
exit/b

:repair
echo %0 %*
:: Restore services (undo only the changes made by this script, not whatever blocking was done by other means)
sc config wuauserv type= share depend= rpcss %.%
sc config TrustedInstaller type= own depend= / %.%
:: Remove any IFEO blocking done by past scripts
set eo=DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Service WindowsUpdateElevatedInstaller LocationNotificationWindows InstallAgentUserBroker
set eo=%eo% UpdateNotificationMgr DataUsageLiveTileTask Windows10UpgraderApp WindowsActionDialog SpeechModelDownload WerFaultSecure
set eo=%eo% GetCurrentRollback WindowsUpdateBox Windows10Upgrade TrustedInstaller MusNotification DiagTrackRunner CompatTelRunner
set eo=%eo% WinREBootApp64 WinREBootApp32 UNPUXLauncher SpeechRuntime MusNotifyIcon PilotshubApp InstallAgent dstokenclean wsqmcons
set eo=%eo% disksnapshot osrssupdate wuapihost WaaSMedic UsoClient UNPUXHost SIHClient setupprep SetupHost osrssinst EOSNotify wusa
set eo=%eo% WerFault TiWorker SearchUI DWTRIG20 dusmtask dmclient appidtel wuauclt wermgr DFDWiz remsh reach HxTsr DWWIN DW20 GWX
for %%# in (%eo%) do reg delete "%ifeo%\%%#.exe" /f %.%
:: Restore notification hijacking
>"%SystemRoot%\WUTRefresh.bat" echo/@start "WUTRefresh" /min wscript.exe /e:JScript "%f0%" WUTRefresh
for %%# in (MusNotification EOSNotify) do reg add "%ifeo%\%%#.exe" /v Debugger /d "%SystemRoot%\WUTRefresh.bat" /f %.%
:: Remove pending instance safeguard
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WUT.bat" /v Pending /f %.%
:: Refresh menu
call :refresh repair
:: Open Update Diagnostic
start "wud" msdt.exe /id WindowsUpdateDiagnostic %.%
:: Open official update troubleshooter page
start https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027322/windows-update-troubleshooter %.%
exit/b

:report
echo %0 %*
call :flip wermgr
reg add "%menu%\shell\81Report"    /v MUIVerb /d "Report    %[T]% %toggle%" /f %.%
for %%# in (%reporter%) do if defined block ( reg delete "%ifeo%\%%#.exe" /f %.% ) else (
 reg add "%ifeo%\%%#.exe" /v Debugger /d "%noop%" /f %.% &taskkill /im "%%#.exe" /t /f %.%
)
exit/b

:speech
echo %0 %*
call :flip SpeechRuntime
reg add "%menu%\shell\82Speech"    /v MUIVerb /d "Speech    %[T]% %toggle%" /f %.%
for %%# in (%speecher%) do if defined block ( reg delete "%ifeo%\%%#.exe" /f %.% ) else (
 reg add "%ifeo%\%%#.exe" /v Debugger /d "%noop%" /f %.% &taskkill /im "%%#.exe" /t /f %.%
)
exit/b

:search
echo %0 %*
call :flip SearchUI
reg add "%menu%\shell\83Search"    /v MUIVerb /d "SearchUI  %[T]% %toggle%" /f %.%
for %%# in (%searcher%) do if defined block ( reg delete "%ifeo%\%%#.exe" /f %.% ) else (
 reg add "%ifeo%\%%#.exe" /v Debugger /d "%noop%" /f %.% &taskkill /im "%%#.exe" /t /f %.%
)
exit/b

:defender
echo %0 %*
set "s10=$t=1;$toggle='stopped'; if((Get-MpPreference).DisableRealtimeMonitoring){$t=0;$toggle='enabled';}"
set "s11=Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $t"
set "s12=Set-MpPreference -DisableBehaviorMonitoring $t"
set "s13=Set-MpPreference -DisableIOAVProtection $t"
set "s14=write-host $toggle"
for /f "delims=" %%# in ('call powershell.exe -c "%s10%;%s11%;%s12%;%s13%;%s14%;"') do set "toggle=%%#"
reg add "%menu%\shell\84Defender"  /v MUIVerb /d "Defender  %[T]% %toggle%" /f %.%
exit/b

:update_defender - triggered from WScript to get definitions from MMPC, regardless of updates being blocked
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq MpCmdRun.exe" | find ".exe" %.%
if not errorlevel 1 exit/b
pushd %ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender
call MpCmdRun.exe -removedefinitions -dynamicsignatures
call MpCmdRun.exe -SignatureUpdate -MMPC
exit/b

:setup
echo %0 %*
pushd %SystemRoot%
if /i "%~f0"=="%f0%" (set "initial_setup=") else copy /y "%~f0" "%f0%" %.%
:: Create WUTUndo for emergencies
 >WUTUndo.bat echo/pushd %%~dp0system32\config
>>WUTUndo.bat echo/reg load HKLM\WUTUndo1 SOFTWARE
>>WUTUndo.bat echo/set "koff=HKLM\WUTUndo1\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options" ^&set "kon=%ifeo%"
>>WUTUndo.bat echo/for %%%%B in (%exe%) do for %%%%K in ("%%koff%%" "%%kon%%") do reg delete "%%%%~K\%%%%B.exe" /f 2^>nul
>>WUTUndo.bat echo/reg unload HKLM\WUTUndo1
>>WUTUndo.bat echo/reg load HKLM\WUTUndo2 SYSTEM
>>WUTUndo.bat echo/for %%%%K in (WUTUndo2 SYSTEM) do (
>>WUTUndo.bat echo/ reg delete "HKLM\%%%%~K\ControlSet001\Services\TrustedInstaller" /v DependOnService /f 2^>nul
>>WUTUndo.bat echo/ reg delete "HKLM\%%%%~K\CurrentControlSet\Services\TrustedInstaller" /v DependOnService /f 2^>nul
>>WUTUndo.bat echo/)
>>WUTUndo.bat echo/reg unload HKLM\WUTUndo2
:: Create WUTRefresh to hijack update notifications and refresh context menu in addition to preventing forced reboots
>WUTRefresh.bat echo/@start "WUTRefresh" /min wscript.exe /e:JScript "%f0%" WUTRefresh
:: Create tasks to run context menu entries with proper access and no output window
start "WUT" wscript /e:JScript "%~f0" cmd "call `%~f0` setup_schtasks"
:: WUT options
for %%# in (NoBlock NoRefresh) do reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WUT.bat" /v %%# /d "Enable" /f %.%
call :toggle blocking
exit/b

:setup_schtasks - no stalling separate process
set "strun=wscript.exe /e:JScript \"%f0%\" run%window%"
for %%t in (refresh lists upgrades installs downloads service repair report speech search defender toggle renew remove) do (
 schtasks /create /ru "%username%" /sc once /tn "WUT\%%t" /tr "%strun% %%t" /st "00:00:00" /it /rl highest /f %.%
)
for %%t in (hide unhide apply) do for /l %%n in (101,1,116) do (
 schtasks /create /ru "%username%" /sc once /tn "WUT\%%t\%%n" /tr "%strun% %%t %%n" /st "00:00:00" /it /rl highest /f %.%
)
exit/b

:renew
echo %0 %*
echo Renewing from internet - old version saved as %SystemRoot%\WUT.old
pushd %SystemRoot%
if exist WUT.new del /f /q WUT.new %.%
call wscript /e:JScript "%~f0" renew "https://pastebin.com/raw/gNsLEWJe" "%SystemRoot%\WUT.new"
if exist WUT.new copy /y "%f0%" WUT.old %.% &copy /y WUT.new "%f0%" %.% &del /f /q WUT.new %.%
start "WUT" "%f0%" setup renew %.%
exit/b

:remove
echo %0 %*
for %%# in (NoBlock NoRefresh) do reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WUT.bat" /v %%# /d "Disable" /f %.%
call :toggle off
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WUT.bat" /f %.%
for %%# in ("" "0pending" "1hide" "2unhide" "3apply") do reg delete "%menu%%%~#" /f %.%
for %%t in (refresh lists upgrades installs downloads service repair report speech search defender toggle renew remove) do (
 schtasks /delete /tn "WUT\%%t" /f %.%
)
for %%t in (hide unhide apply) do for /l %%n in (101,1,116) do schtasks /delete /tn "WUT\%%t\%%n" /f %.%
for %%t in (hide unhide apply) do schtasks /delete /tn "WUT\%%t" /f %.%
schtasks /delete /tn "WUT" /f %.%
sc config wuauserv type= share depend= rpcss %.%
sc config TrustedInstaller type= own depend= / %.%
pushd %SystemRoot%
del /f /q WUT.bat WUT.old DefenderManualUpdate.bat WUTRefresh.bat WUTUndo.bat "%f0%" %.%
exit/b

:flip %1:exe
call :reg_query "%ifeo%\%~1.exe" Debugger block
if defined block (set "toggle=enabled") else set "toggle=blocked"
exit/b

:status %1:exe
call :reg_query "%ifeo%\%~1.exe" Debugger block
if defined block (set "toggle=blocked") else set "toggle=enabled"
exit/b

:reg_query %1:KeyName %2:ValueName %3:OutputVariable %4:other_options[example: "/t REG_DWORD"]
setlocal & for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%s in ('reg query "%~1" /v "%~2" /z 2^>nul') do set "rq=%%s" & call set "rv=%%rq:*)    =%%"
endlocal & set "%~3=%rv%" & exit/b &rem                                         AveYo: call :reg_query "HKCU\MyKey" "MyValue" MyVar

::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:JScript_functions                                                                 AveYo: Switch syntax highlighter to 'javascript'
::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
f0=WSH.ScriptFullName; run=WSH.Arguments(0); args=''; for(i=1;i<WSH.Arguments.length;i++) args+=' "'+WSH.Arguments(i)+'"';
function sex(exe,args){WSH.CreateObject('Shell.Application').ShellExecute(exe,args,'','',0);}; function reg(s){ sex('reg.exe',s); }

// Open external commands in new hidden cmd instance - backquotes replaced to quotes
if (run=='cmd') sex('cmd','/c '+args.replace(/`/g,'"'));

// Context menu entries trigger - elevated with no popups
if (run=='schtasks') sex('SCHTASKS.EXE','/Run /TN '+args);

// Shift to CMD if loaded by WScript - pass arguments, prevent loop, run as admin at setup, hide window at context-menu
function cmd(adm,win){WSH.CreateObject('Shell.Application').ShellExecute('cmd','/c call "'+f0+'" shift "'+f0+'"'+args,'',adm,win);}
if (run=='run') cmd('',1); if (run=='runhide') cmd('',0); if (run=='runas') cmd('runas',1); if (run=='runashide') cmd('runas',0);

if (run=='renew') {
  // renew script over internet
  try{
  downloader=WSH.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
  if (downloader===null) downloader=WSH.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest");
  if (downloader===null) downloader=WSH.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP");
  if (downloader===null) downloader=WSH.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  downloader.Open("GET",WSH.Arguments(1),false); downloader.Send(); oASI=downloader.ResponseBody(); downloader=undefined;
  oASO=WSH.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream"); oASO.type=1; oASO.Mode=3; oASO.Open; oASO.Write(oASI); oASI=undefined;
  oASO.SaveToFile(WSH.Arguments(2)); oASO.Close();
  }catch(e){} // supress all errors since we're working with com objects
}

// WUT Hide/Unhide/Apply lists
if (run=='WUTRefresh' || run=='hide' || run=='unhide' || run=='apply') {
  SRP=GetObject("winmgmts:StdRegProv"); pending=SRP.GetStringValue(2147483650,'SOFTWARE\\WUT.bat','Pending');
  if (pending===0) WSH.quit(); else SRP.SetStringValue(2147483650,'SOFTWARE\\WUT.bat','Pending','yes'); // prevent instances
  k='HKCR\\DesktopBackground\\shell\\WUT'; hk=k+'1hide'; uk=k+'2unhide'; ik=k+'3apply'; pk=k+'0pending';           // set list keys
  reg('delete "'+hk+'" /f'); reg('delete "'+uk+'" /f'); reg('delete "'+ik+'" /f');                               // delete previous
  reg('add "'+pk+'" /v MUIVerb /d "Pending.." /f'); reg('add "'+pk+'" /v SubCommands /d "" /f');             // add Pending.. entry
  // Check for updates
  count=0; wuthide=[]; wutunhide=[];
  try{
  session=WSH.CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session"); reboot=WSH.CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.SystemInfo").RebootRequired;
  searcher=session.CreateUpdateSearcher();
  sresult=searcher.Search("IsInstalled=0"); Updatelist=sresult.Updates; count=sresult.Updates.Count;
  for(i=0;i<count;i++) {
    itemTitle=Updatelist.Item(i).Title;
    minsize=Updatelist.Item(i).MinDownloadSize; maxsize=Updatelist.Item(i).MaxDownloadSize; wutsize='';
    if (maxsize > 1073741824) wutsize=' ['+Math.round(minsize/10737418.24)/100+' - '+Math.round(maxsize/10737418.24)/100+'GB]';
    else if (maxsize > 1048576) wutsize=' ['+Math.round(minsize/10485.76)/100+' - '+Math.round(maxsize/10485.76)/100+'MB]';
    else if (maxsize > 1024) wutsize=' ['+Math.round(minsize/10.24)/100+' - '+Math.round(maxsize/10.24)/100+'KB]';
    else if (maxsize > 0) wutsize=' ['+(minsize)+' - '+(maxsize)+'B]';
    wutTitle=Updatelist.Item(i).Title + wutsize;
    if (run=='apply' && WSH.Arguments(1).indexOf(itemTitle) > -1) {
      // Add matching entry to UpdateColl
      UpdateColl=WSH.CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl"); UpdateColl.Add(Updatelist.Item(i));
      // Download update
      downloader=session.CreateUpdateDownloader(); downloader.Updates=UpdateColl; dresult=downloader.Download();
      if (dresult.ResultCode==2) {
        // Unblock apply
        sex('sc','config TrustedInstaller type= own depend= /');
        KeyPath='SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Image File Execution Options\\wuauclt.exe';
        SRP.DeleteKey(2147483650,KeyPath);
        WSH.Sleep(1000);
        //Apply update
        installer=session.CreateUpdateInstaller(); installer.Updates=UpdateColl; iresult=installer.Install();
        if (iresult.ResultCode==2) continue;
      }
    }
    // hide and unhide are very simple bool flip compared to apply
    if (run=='hide' && WSH.Arguments(1).indexOf(itemTitle) > -1) {
      Updatelist.Item(i).IsHidden=true; wutunhide.push(wutTitle); continue;
    }
    if (run=='unhide' && WSH.Arguments(1).indexOf(itemTitle) > -1) {
      Updatelist.Item(i).IsHidden=false; wuthide.push(wutTitle); continue;
    }
    // Trigger :update_defender to manually refresh definitions from MMPC
    if (Updatelist.Item(i).IsHidden===false && itemTitle.indexOf('(Definition') > -1) {
      sex('cmd','/c call "'+f0+'" update_defender');
    }
    // Sorting lists
    if (Updatelist.Item(i).IsHidden) wutunhide.push(wutTitle); else wuthide.push(wutTitle);
  }
  // Generate Hide context menu
  if (wuthide.length>0){
    for(i=101,n=wuthide.length+101;i<n;i++) {
      reg('add "'+hk+'\\shell\\'+i+'" /v MUIVerb /d "'+wuthide[i-101]+'" /f');
      reg('add "'+hk+'\\shell\\'+i+'\\command" /ve /d "wscript.exe /e:JScript \\"'+f0+'\\" schtasks WUT\\hide\\'+i+'" /f');
    }
    reg('add "'+hk+'" /v SubCommands /d "" /f');
    reg('add "'+hk+'" /v MUIVerb /d "Hide '+"\t"+wuthide.length+'" /f');
  }
  // Generate Unhide context menu
  if (wutunhide.length>0){
    for(i=101,n=wutunhide.length+101;i<n;i++) {
      reg('add "'+uk+'\\shell\\'+i+'" /v MUIVerb /d "'+wutunhide[i-101]+'" /f');
      reg('add "'+uk+'\\shell\\'+i+'\\command" /ve /d "wscript.exe /e:JScript \\"'+f0+'\\" schtasks WUT\\unhide\\'+i+'" /f');
    }
    reg('add "'+uk+'" /v SubCommands /d "" /f');
    reg('add "'+uk+'" /v MUIVerb /d "Unhide '+"\t"+wutunhide.length+'" /f');
  }
  // Generate Apply context menu
  if (wuthide.length>0){
    for(i=101,n=wuthide.length+101;i<n;i++) {
      reg('add "'+ik+'\\shell\\'+i+'" /v MUIVerb /d "'+wuthide[i-101]+'" /f');
      reg('add "'+ik+'\\shell\\'+i+'\\command" /ve /d "wscript.exe /e:JScript \\"'+f0+'\\" schtasks WUT\\apply\\'+i+'" /f');
    }
    reg('add "'+ik+'" /v SubCommands /d "" /f');
    reg('add "'+ik+'" /v MUIVerb /d "Apply '+"\t"+((reboot) ? 'must reboot' : wuthide.length)+'" /f');
  }
  }catch(e){} // supress all errors since we're working with com objects
  reg('delete "'+pk+'" /f'); SRP.DeleteValue(2147483650,'SOFTWARE\\WUT.bat','Pending'); // Remove Pending.. temporary entry
}
//
```

*Last updated for v10.0 final. Up-to-date code on pastebin link above.*

Comment: Any chance you could tell me how you got your windows menus to have a black background?!

Comment: That's a high-contrast-based theme, available here: https://pastebin.com/fA3t5Sd2

Answer (score 3):

## Finally found a permanent fix that just *works*

After trying literally *every* trick in the book, I have always been bested by Windows Update. I've tried every solution here plus tons of other sources, and Windows constantly found ways to thwart my plans.

***Until about 6 months ago...***

I have found a permanent solution for disabling ALL windows updates FOREVER regardless of whether the service or anything else is running. I have figured out this method with the help of many different sources that had to do with many different things. Overall, I found this method myself with the use of bits and pieces of other information used to do things that were not all related to this, but it works. And it works ***absolutely beautifully.***

1. Install **Acrylic DNS Proxy** from [**here**](https://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicHome)

It is basically a souped up version of the windows hosts file that allows you to add functions like wildcards, which is necessary in our case because of the many sources windows gets its updates from.

2. Follow the instructions [**here**](https://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicWindows10Configuration) to make Acrylic start doing its job in Win 10. Pretty simple stuff.
3. Go to your start menu, and click "**Edit Acrylic Hosts File**" under All Programs, shown [**here**](http://prntscr.com/l5q3su)
4. Add these lines to the bottom of the hosts file, with no # signs in front.

> 0.0.0.0 windowsupdate.microsoft.com 
>   0.0.0.0 *.windowsupdate.microsoft.com 
>   0.0.0.0 *.update.microsoft.com 
>   0.0.0.0 windowsupdate.com 
>   0.0.0.0 *.windowsupdate.com 
>   0.0.0.0 download.windowsupdate.com 
>   0.0.0.0 download.microsoft.com 
>   0.0.0.0 *.download.windowsupdate.com 
>   0.0.0.0 wustat.windows.com 
>   0.0.0.0 ntservicepack.microsoft.com 
>   0.0.0.0 stats.microsoft.com

Now the bottom of the file should look like [**this**](http://prntscr.com/l5q6c4). 
Save and close the file.

5. Open task manager, go to services tab, click "Open Services" at the bottom, select **Acrylic DNS Proxy** and click [**this button**](https://prnt.sc/l5pw97) with the red circle to restart the service.

***FINISHED***

Now your Acrylic buddy should have your back and constantly keep an keen eye on Microsoft's Big Brother tactics to make sure they can't force poor old you to install updates that *mess up your PC completely* which they have at least a fourth of the time they did it on both my home PC and my **Surface Pro** *which is supposed to be the PC BUILT for Windows, right??? Cmon, Microsoft!*

7. Check to make sure it's working by pinging any one of the websites in the code above. Open cmd and type

> ping windowsupdate.microsoft.com

If [**these**](https://prnt.sc/l5q3i2) are your results, you will be golden from now on!!

Note: in my experience, this has not slowed my PC at all. It also does not reroute any Internet traffic besides requests to the sources Windows uses to update or check for updates, so very similar to the hosts file. It also uses basically the same format as the hosts file. This has also successfully disabled the reinstall of junk that windows keeps placing on my computer that gives that giant colored screen saying  something like "you must update or your computer will implode". Obviously I don't remember what the warning said since it's been so long since I've gotten it (due to completely successful blocking 6 months or so ago), but it was the most annoying thing I've ever seen.

Comment: hahahaha. oh man. this answer is just. wow. smart. very smart. i just can't emphasize how good this answer is. millions of people come at the front door where there is hundreds of defenses. but this solution comes at the side where there are no defenses and building defenses would not really be possible because of the design of the internet.

Comment: if you have a fancy router/gateway/home-networking-box with fancy DNS features... then you could IMO do something similar.

Answer (score 3):

Disabling windows updates requires you to disable:

- Windows Update (wuauserv)
- Windows Update Medic Service (WaaSMedicSvc)
- Update Orchestrator Service (UsoSvc)

And possibly this task:

```
schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\Automatic App Update" /Disable
```

Things change with each version of Windows, but I think these should do. For changing the services' startup option to disabled, you need appropriate permissions in registry (you cannot do it manually through Services GUI). You can get the needed permissions with [SetACL](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/) tool. Startup parameters for services in registry can be found in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`. The value for "disabled" is dword:4.

Answer (score 1):

## Disable Update Service

1. <kbd>Win+R</kbd> > `services.msc`
2. Double click Windows Update and change the Startup Type to Disabled. To re-enable, go back to services and change it to automatic.

[image]

Source: [How To Control Windows 10 Updates](https://techgage.com/article/taking-back-control-of-windows-10-updates/)

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I want not only to control when Windows Updates go, but also to limit all installed applications from out of control on their online updates.

So my simple one stop solution is : 
1. Bloc the internet access for the host on router side. None of programs or services installed on the host can access internet. Of-cause Windows Updates is blocked too.

2. Install a Squid Proxy Server on local network and give the proxy to those applications that you allow them to go internet. Do not set proxy on Control Panel | Internet Option, cause that is global OS wide proxy which voids the step 1 at all.

Most applications support per application based proxy setting, such as Chrome, Firefox, All kind of Games etc.

3. For those applications that don't support local proxy setting, use NAS cloud 
   fold as Cloud Proxy. For example, Office 365 suits doesn't support per program proxy. You can then setup a NAS Cloud Sync (for example, Synology NAS has Cloud sync to sync OneDrive) to sync conents in a NAS fold, then you use that fold as Office 365's local fold. Extra benefits of this way is you get really fast response on big files, cause you are using local network speed to access OneDrive.

By doing these, your computer's internet accessing is greatly controlled by yourself, no one can mess you up.

Whenever you want update Windows, set Control Panel | Internet Option to use your local proxy, hence Windows can update your OS. After that, turn off the global proxy immediately to set your computer into a peace, quite world again.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found a solution to this issue. I am on Windows 10 Home Edition version 1909. The *only* thing that works is running the following Batch Script repeatedly via Task Scheduler:

```
sc stop "BITS"
sc config "BITS" start= disabled
sc config "BITS" obj= ".\Guest" password= ""
sc stop "UsoSvc"
sc config "UsoSvc" start= disabled
sc config "UsoSvc" obj= ".\Guest" password= ""
sc stop "wuauserv"
sc config "wuauserv" start= disabled
sc config "wuauserv" obj= ".\Guest" password= ""
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WaaSMedicSvc /v START /t REG_DWORD /d 0x0000004 /f
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WaaSMedicSvc /v ObjectName /t REG_SZ /d .\Guest /f
```

Put the above in a .bat file and run it on Task Scheduler on a 5 minute schedule. This will repeatedly disable all processes Windows keeps enabling automatically (Background Intelligent Transfer Service, Update Orchestrator Service, Windows Update, and Windows Update Medic Service). It's necessary to keep these processes disabled for updates to be suppressed. Admittedly, this is not a nice solution but it gets the job done. I've been running this for over a year without any issues now.

Answer (score 1):

### I. The official Microsoft way to stop all automatic updates

Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> > *Update & Security* >
*Advanced options* (in the right pane).

Under *Pause updates*, it says :
[*Temporarily pause updates from being installed on this device for up
to 35 days.
When you reach the pause limit, your device will need to get new
updates before you can pause again.*](https://www.minitool.com/news/win10-home-pause-updates-for-35-days.html)

The reason I don't use the Microsoft official way to stop all
automatic updates,
is that I prefer my own *unofficial* way, which I will dedicate the
rest of this answer to.

***Disclaimer***.
If you try any of the tips below, it's all at your own responsibility.

### II. My method to permanently stop all automatic updates

My method: *block the `wuauserv` and `WaaSMedicSvc`  services
by renaming them in the registry*.
<sup>1</sup>
This has served me well for many years.
<sup>2</sup>
It's the closest I can get to that *on/off* switch that
Microsoft stubbornly refuses to give us.
For more details on *how* to do this, read on.

#### 1. Precautionary actions. (Don't skip! – Better safe than sorry.)

Before moving on, I strongly recommend saving a copy of the Windows
Services registry settings.

Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type (or paste) `regedit` and
hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
In the navigation bar, paste `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`
and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Right-click `Services` and choose *Export*.
Make sure you save the backup `.reg` file in a safe place where
you *will remember* how to find it – should you ever need it.
Expect the file size to be just below 8 MB.
<sup>3</sup>

[image: Export the 'Services' registry key - keep the backup safe!]

The most vulnerable registry key in this context is :
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv`
so it's a good idea to also export that key into its own `.reg` file.
Remember where you keep it!

#### 2. Block the `wuauserv` and `WaaSMedicSvc` services in the registry

Next scroll down to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv`.

Right-click `wuauserv`, click *Rename* and add the suffix
`-BLOCKED!!` so that the key's new name becomes `wuauserv-BLOCKED!!`.

Likewise, rename
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WaaSMedicSvc`
to `WaaSMedicSvc-BLOCKED!!`.

Now press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, click *Update & Security*,
and then *Check for updates*.
Expect to get an *Error encountered* as in the screenshot below.

[image: When trying to run Windows Update, expect an error.]

If you see this error, it confirms that you have successfully disabled
Windows Update.
The error was immediate when I tried this, but you may have to
restart the computer for the change to take effect.
Possible error numbers include `0x80040154`, `0x80070002`,
`0x80070005`, `0x80070424`, `0x80080005`.

#### 3. How to enable Windows Update again

When you later want to *enable* Windows Update again,
just rename the registry key back to its original name `wuauserv`.
(You shouldn't need to rename/unblock `WaaSMedicSvc-BLOCKED!!`.)

Before renaming back, you have to delete the `wuauserv` key if it
exists.
*Don't delete `wuauserv-BLOCKED!!` or `WaaSMedicSvc-BLOCKED!!`*
<sup>4</sup>

After renaming back, you need to make a *software restart*
(<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> followed by <kbd>u</kbd> and
<kbd>r</kbd>) to activate Windows Update again.

*Note!*
A *hardware restart* – just shutting down and then restarting by
pressing the physical power button – will ***not*** start Windows
Update.

##### What if you still get *Error encountered*?

What if you unblocked the `wuauserv` registry key, restarted the
computer (<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>),
and *still* get *Error encountered* when trying to run Windows Update?

*Remedy:* check that the Windows Update (wuauserv) *service* is
running, as follows.

Open *Windows Services*, press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>,
type `services.msc` (and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
Sort by name, look for *Windows Update* and double-click that service.

If the *wuauserv* service is *disabled*, you need to set it to
*Manual*.

[image: In 'services.msc', Windows Update must not be disabled.]

#### 4. The `wuauserv` registry key will be automatically recreated

If you block `wuauserv` as describe in Section 2 above, Windows will
automatically and silently recreate the `wuauserv` and `WaaSMedicSvc`
registry keys as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Windows silently and automatically recreates some values.]

This is *not* enough to make Windows Update run again.

#### 5. Windows Update may display as if it works, even when it doesn't

The surest way to know if Windows Update has suddenly started to
run again (without your consent), is to go to *Settings* >
*Update & Security* > *Windows Update*.
If you see an error, then Windows Update is still successfully
blocked.

But even if you see a green checkmark as in the screenshot below,
Windows Update might still be blocked.
You could click *Check for updates* to see if there is an error
or not.
However, if there *isn't* an error, Windows Update will start to
download any new updates and install them on the next restart.

[image: Windows Update may falsely display as if it is working.]

This might not be what you want.
To gain more control, run [`wushowhide.diagcab`](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/2/f22d5fdb-59cd-4275-8c95-1be17bf70b21/wushowhide.diagcab) which allows
to prevent (*hide*) any updates that you don't want.

#### 6. Some caveats

If you decide to block Windows Update, beware that any action that
depends on it will fail.
To restore it, all you need to do is remove the `BLOCKED!!` suffix
from the `wuauserv` registry key,
and restart the computer
(<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>).
The following list is *not* comprehensive.

- System File Check (`SFC`) fails.
  – I once ran `sfc /VERIFYONLY`,
  and the [Trusted Installer](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/what-is-trustedinstaller-and-why-does-it-keep-me-from-renaming-files/)
  hijacked my laptop for about 45 minutes. (!)
  <sup>5</sup>
- `wsl.exe --install` fails with `0x80070005`.
- `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth` fails.

#### 7. System Restore

I *disable* the System Restore feature because when it kicks in,
it can (temporarily) make the system slow and unresponsive.
– System Restore has prevented me from using my computer for about
half an hour or even longer.
That's why I prefer disabling System Restore altogether.

Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and paste
`systempropertiesprotection` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Click *Configure...* and check *Disable system protection*.
Click *OK* twice.

#### 8. What do *wuauserv*, *WaaSMedicSvc*, *UsoSvc* stand for?

The letters in *wuauserv* stand for **w**indows **u**pdate
**au**tomatic **serv**ice.
*WaaSMedicSvc* stands for Windows Update Medic Service.
*UsoSvc* stands for Update Orchestrator Service.

#### References

- [Windows 10 Updates Can Be Paused for 35 Days](https://www.minitool.com/news/win10-home-pause-updates-for-35-days.html)
- [Pause Updates until a Selected Date for up to 35 Days](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/73441-pause-updates-resume-updates-windows-update-windows-10-a.html#option2)
- [*Never, ever* run `sc delete`.
  – It will destroy your registry!](https://superuser.com/q/1585391)
- [Direct link to download `wushowhide.diagcab`.](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/2/f22d5fdb-59cd-4275-8c95-1be17bf70b21/wushowhide.diagcab)
- [`ControlSet001` and `ControlSet002` are backups of
  `CurrentControlSet`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/291528)
- [More on `CurrentControlSet` and its backups.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150217152952/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100010)
- [What Is TrustedInstaller?](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/what-is-trustedinstaller-and-why-does-it-keep-me-from-renaming-files/)
- [Fix SrTasks.exe High Disk usage in Windows 11/10 |
  *4) Turn off System Restore*](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/srtasks-exe-shows-high-disk-usage)

---

<sup>1</sup>
[*Never, ever* run `sc delete`](https://superuser.com/q/1585391)!
– It will destroy your registry.

<sup>2</sup>
For example, in 2018 I updated to version 1803 (build 17134).
I didn't let Windows Update run again until April 2022, when it
installed version 21H2 (build 19044.1682).
That's almost four years without a single update.

<sup>3</sup>
You can store the `.reg` file wherever you want.
I store it in `C:\Downloads\Win10\RegBkp\HKLM\services`
under the name `HKLM%SYSTEM%CurrentControlSet%Services.reg`.

<sup>4</sup>
If you delete it by mistake, I sure hope you still have the backup
I asked you to save by exporting to a `.reg` file!
Deleting the key is exactly what `sc delete` does.
That's why I advise you never to run it.

<sup>5</sup>
I have also tried disabling the `TrustedInstaller` by replacing
`TiWorker.exe` with an empty file, but that's not an option.
Windows cannot even restart normally when the `TrustedInstaller`
is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

The following commands works as of March 2023. Run (paste) them in Admin console. Wait for 10 seconds and do it again.

```
sc stop WaasMedicSvc
sc stop bits
net stop wuauserv
net stop WaasMedicSvc
net stop bits
sc config bits start=disabled
sc config wuauserv start=disabled
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WaaSMedicSvc /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f
schtasks /Change /DISABLE /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\Scheduled Start"
```

Answer (score 0):

2 years later and billions of unsaved works lost by the update mechanism of Microsoft, there is finally a major update that solves the problem.

[Windows 10 Creators Update now available](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) ([Direct Download](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=799445))

After installing the update the user will finally asked again (like those insignificant 20+ years before) if s/he wants the update to be applied:

[image: win10 new old update message]

Sometimes I wonder who is behind those decisions...

After the update you have more options regarding the update times. For stopping them, go to **Windows Update Settings > Advanced Options > Pause Updates > ON**.

[image: pause updates]

Under Restart Options you also find a new option for update notifications:

[image: notification updates]

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: "a way to stop auto updates" - This is one way to get rid of the forced auto updates. And for stopping them, go to Windows Update Settings > Advanced Options > Pause Updates > ON. I have added this to the answer. (You have even more options after the Windows Update.)

Answer (score 0):

While I disabled update in Services and Group Policy Editor, it still turns back on from time to time. Then I have to manually turn them off in Services. Doing this via the GUI is troublesome, so I wrote a batch script. It stops and disables `Background Intelligent Transfer Service` and `Windows Update`.

```
@echo off

net stop wuauserv
net stop BITS

sc config wuauserv start= disabled
sc config BITS start= disabled

pause
```

I'm also using (not specifically for this) a light network monitor tool (Bandwidth Monitor), so I know when there's an activity (an icon at the system tray). If I see an activity when there shouldn't be any, I know Windows Update turned back on. Then I run the script and it's off.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for Windows 10 Home:

https://github.com/WereDev/Wu10Man

this is up to date (2020) open source program that can disable the Windows
Update service.

Answer (score -1):

### Disable all windows updates by PowerShell

(run PowerShell as Administrator)

```
Clear-Host

$WindowsUpdatePath = "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\"
$AutoUpdatePath = "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"

If(Test-Path -Path $WindowsUpdatePath) {
    Remove-Item -Path $WindowsUpdatePath -Recurse
}

New-Item $WindowsUpdatePath -Force
New-Item $AutoUpdatePath -Force

Set-ItemProperty -Path $AutoUpdatePath -Name NoAutoUpdate -Value 1

Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\" | Disable-ScheduledTask

takeown /F C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator /A /R
icacls C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator /grant Administrators:F /T

Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\" | Disable-ScheduledTask

Stop-Service wuauserv
Set-Service wuauserv -StartupType Disabled

Write-Output "All Windows Updates were disabled"
```

Comment: doesn't work, service is restarted anyway

Comment: Seems like you missed taking out the Medic...