# Using an older display driver for Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

Is there a way to simply **replace the default NVidia graphics driver installed with Windows 10, with an older version**, and prevent Windows 10 from installing the updated one in the future?

I have a several years old laptop which is running well, an i7, 8GB Fujitsu with an SSD, and Windows 8.1 installed. However, the graphics card ([NVidia GeForce GT 640M LE](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gt-640m-le/specifications)) only works properly with an older driver from 2015. A Windows upgrade to the driver in late 2015 made the OS unbootable, and the second time I gave in to the nagging Windows 10 upgrade created the same issue and made me have to reinstall Windows 8.1 from scratch.

NVidia page for newer GeForce driver versions also states that [Fujitsu notebooks are not supported](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/102072), and the last driver available for download on the Fujitsu page is also from 02/2015 (but also Windows 10 compatible).

But since our company licensing policy states that I should switch to Windows 10, I am wondering if there is a way to (easily) replace the driver included with the new Windows setup, or even better, switch it during the installation.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [DDU (Display Driver Uninstaller)](http://www.wagnardmobile.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=279&sid=e7992ac286f5db4ccb5b9ecab58fc24a). First you should download the older driver then run DDU as administrator. It will reboot into safemode and continue running there, you will see an option to disable automatic driver installation in the lower right of the software, click it then click **Clean and restart** to remove the current driver and also remove all files associated with that. I'm pretty sure you know what will be the consequence if you disable the **Windows Automatic Driver installation** so do this at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds promising. I will try it, although I will probably not be installing W10 until next week, but if it works I will get back with how it went.