# How to control Win10 updates

Tags: windows-10, upgrade

Recently my Win10 went through an upgrade and an old software that was working stopped working. Once I restored Windows to a prior date my software became functional again. I want to know

1- How do I get a log of recent upgrades of Win10 to find out what event triggered the change? (Would that upgrade still be recorded even after my restore?)

2- Is there a way of preventing Win10 from performing that particular upgrade again in the future?

Comment: If you are using Windows 10 Professional you can defer the Version 1511 update for awhile, but you really should update to it, so you can all the security fixes released.  You can solve your software problem by simply installing it again.

Comment: See my post here.  http://superuser.com/a/983535/40928

Comment: @Moab - Windows 10 will allow you to defer updates like Version 1511, and your solution with Minitool will work just as well, but eventually the user will have to upgrade to Version 1511.

Comment: Define "have to" you mean W10 will stop working if I don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log of recent updates will have also been rolled back to the restore point, however if you manually trigger windows update it will show you the updates it finds, which will include the one causing issues.

You can then use the official system to hide updates that cause you trouble:

[Windows 10 update hider](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930?utm_source=twitter)

It is a "troubleshooter", but see here for a demonstration of its functionality:

[Example](http://www.howtogeek.com/223864/how-to-uninstall-and-block-updates-and-drivers-on-windows-10/)

Comment: The tool cannot be used to hide or opt out of this particular update.  The update is minatory in this case.

Comment: I suspected as much, looks like newer software or compatibility mode will be required