# prevent a program from creating a certain folder

Tags: windows-10, gpu, hp-pavilion, blacklist

I have a HP dv6-6170us and my AMD GPU is broken (my laptop froze once two months ago and I wasn't able to log in anymore so I tried to reinstall Windows 10 and when I try to install the driver or even enable it the laptop freezes again).

So I tried everything to prevent Windows 10 from automatically installing the driver (even with the MS update hiding tool) nothing worked and Windows always start downloading it when it went online.

The only working method is to meter my WiFi connection but this only works for quickly configured WiFi and no LAN.

What I noticed is that Windows update always create an AMD file and then it installs the driver from it.

If there's a way to prevent the creation of such a folder by blacklisting its name or automaticaly delete any created files it would be great, but sadly I didn't find any way to do that.
If anybody have a solution for my problem I would really appreciate it.

The only real way to fix the GPU is to replace the Motherboard "which I already tried and faced the same problem after a week of using it" or to heat the GPU with a heat gun or let the laptop crash and heat with a "blanket on it!" to reach a certain temperature for an hour or a little longer which I don't intend to try in the moment or at least not until I'm done with my exams in March.

Comment: See my answer here...http://superuser.com/a/983535

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If the folder exists, delete it first. Now (re)create it, then right click the folder, choose `properties` and head to the `security` tab.

Find the `SYSTEM` user, and set `DENY` to write permissions. This means everything but Full Control is checked at the right side below DENY.

SYSTEM is not able to access or write to this folder anymore, which should solve your problem. You can do the same to other users/groups, but the more users/groups you deny, the more chance it has that you are denying yourself access too. Dunno if that is a problem.

If you happen to block yourself you can undo this from the security tab. Because you created the folder, you are the owner too, and thus you can always change permissions.

Comment: And if you're an admin account, you can also change the owner. Which means that you can do everything with every file as admin, even though Windows makes it REALLY annoying for some.

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar trick to avoid Windows creating "System Volume Information" folder.

I create an empty file with that name, then i configure it as Hidden and System (with attrib +h +s command) and also set permissions on it.

So it can not be deleted, renamed, etc.

And so, Windows can not recreate "System Volume Information" folder.

Note: Most done in USB sticks, USB HDD and DATA partitions, ofcourse not on system partition, all people are warned avoiding such special folder has a bad side, for my personal use i can affod it, but some may not.

So, basically you can do the same with such "AMD" folder.

Comment: How is this better than other answer?

Answer (score 0):

I installed a new IAR compiler and editor named SlickEdit. These programs will automatically create subdirectories for configuration, etc. IAR would not create a Debug subdirectory and I was unable to use (compile) code. SlickEdit wanted to create a "My Slickedit Config" subdirectory to store its configuration settings. I pulled my hair out trying all kinds of security settings as described on the Internet but found the solution under:
Windows Security-->Security at a glance-->Virus & threat protection-->Ransomware protection-->Controlled folder access!!! turn this off!!!
Hope that helps