# My Windows 10 is downloading update files. How to stop it immediately?

Tags: windows-10, download, updates

My Windows 10 is downloading update files. How to stop it immediately? I could not find any stop button. 
[image]

Comment: You can stop Windows Update Service (Run > services.msc), but I don't know if it is installing while downloading and you can damage SO integrity...

Comment: Disconnect from the internet with the understand the updates on Windows 10 are required.

Comment: If you want control over windows updates see my answer here....http://superuser.com/a/983535