# How to Force Automatic Updates to Install at a particular time

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I need to control over when Windows 10 downloads and installs updates

I have these PCs for a short time and they are deployed. I need to deliver them will all updates installed and tested.

Question # 1. Can i control when Windows 10 Downloads these updates and installs them?

Questions # 2 How can i tell in 10 what is pending or any progress made with the updates.

Questions # 3 Do we have too manually shutdown the Automatic Update service to get control over when updates are downloaded?

Comment: windows 10 already downloads and install all updates automatically. the win7 dialog is gone

Comment: Not helpful - read the post

Comment: look in settings app, there is an entry for Windows Update **facepalm**

Comment: Please post the reason for the down votes. I don't see any problem with asking a question on how to get some control over the download/update process.

Comment: I've done many searches can can't find a specific answer on how to control downloads and installs. The majority results are about the update to Windows 10 and none seem to address controlling timing of Windows Updates.

Comment: @rheitzman Like magic said, Windows 10 already does what you want. Problem solved.

Comment: Please read the post - I need to force a complete download and complete install of all pending updates in a short period of time. And/or need to be able to prevent downloads while not on the local LAN.

Comment: Please re-read - new edits. It is obvious that automatic updates are being done. For me timing and control of the downloads and installs are the issue.

Comment: Thanks - hopefully those we lead to some answers and not more comments! :) FYI I edited the edits.

Comment: To prevent downloads when not on the local lan enable "metered connection" [Enable Metered Connection to Delay Windows 10 Updates](http://lifehacker.com/enable-metered-connection-to-delay-windows-10-updates-1723316525)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Windows 10 stop installing driver software automatically](http://superuser.com/questions/947706/make-windows-10-stop-installing-driver-software-automatically)

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows updates is a recurring thing so even if you update it all right now that doesn't mean there will not updates in future.

Answer # 1 : [How to schedule Windows Update in Windows 10 Pro](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-schedule-windows-updates-windows-10)

Answer # 2 : Go to Settings > Windows Updates and you can see the progress there
[image] Clicking on Details would show you what's being installed

Answer # 3 : No you don't have to stop the service to control it you just have to work on controlling it based on your needs. Even if you try to stop the service, it will just start on it's own

Other Usefule information
[How to Prevent Windows 10 From Automatically Downloading Updates](http://www.howtogeek.com/224471/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-downloading-updates/)
[3 Ways To Stop Forced Updates](http://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2015/08/26/windows-10-how-to-stop-forced-updates/#3b90630f5d1f)

Comment: Thnaks! #1 did the trick: gpedit.msc `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Update'  Lots of other interesting settings there too. Luckily I have 10 Pro. The other links look good too.