# Where is old good "Updates" option in Windows 10 Control Panel?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, windows-update

I am running Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]. I realized that it no more shows "Updates" option in Control Panel. Quick online search revealed that stuff has been removed in Settings > Update. So I checked it. Realized that it does not provide fine grained control over the updates to be installed and not in the manner that old Updates option in Control Panel used to provide.

I quickly searched and tried all possible solutions provided online to get back the old update option in the Control Panel, but they did not worked.

- [Some](http://d3vmax.com/2015/02/24/enable-windows-update-in-control-panel-windows-10-build-9926/) asked to do some registry edits...but somehow the registry they asked to add is locked/unmodifyable even after opening `regedit` as Admin. This is also what experienced by other users as they replied in those threads suggesting modifying registry. This seem to work in earlier test builds but no more in official licensed Windows 10.
- Another thread on [Microsoft Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0ee15c34-ce6d-40a2-b5f3-3c18189e75c8/forum-faq-how-to-show-windows-update-in-control-panel-in-clean-installation-of-windows-10?forum=WinPreview2014General)
- Few more threads: [1](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/windows-10-build-9926-wheres-windows-update), [2](http://www.tenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/12542-add-windows-update-back-control-panel-windows-10-a.html)

So my concern:

- Does anyone here succeeded to get back the good old updates in Windows 10 [Version 10.0.10586]?
- Or is anyone simply able to port old Windows update panel by copy pasting system files? (I remember I porting Windows 7 gadgets to Windows 8.1 by copy pasting files in System32 folder after Microsoft dropped the gadget support. I used to love them a lot, especially All Cpu Meter which showed all my 8 cpu cores' load and temprature...such a utility, need to try the same in Windows 10)
- Whats the matter, is Microsoft not willing to give that fine grained control over updates?

**Edit**

This is indeed bad situation as confirmed on my [answers.microsoft thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/get-old-updates-window-in-control-panel-in-windows/cd6f7c17-bf7d-447e-8565-5638ecd58833).

Comment: Does not exist in Windows 10 because of the Insider Preview opt-in functionality.  Updates are more or less mandatory so less control is warranted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is gone in Windows 10, Windows Updates are now mandatory and you have no control over what it installs, including drivers, no way to bring it back like it was in previous versions of Windows, there is a 3rd party tool that will do it though, [see my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/947706/make-windows-10-stop-installing-driver-software-automatically/983535#983535)

Comment: actually that update window used to control many types of update, Windows security update, Windows Defender updates, Office updates, Visual Studio updates, SQL Server updates, Windows driver updates... I guess that was for All-Microsoft softwares. So forcing all these updates is simply stupidity...many times those updates used to be huge specially in case of Visual Studio, SQL Server and Office and I almost always opted out of them as they would consume precious storage. Also correct it is to force SQL database server updates? Such update should not be forced right???

Comment: ...or am I missing something and those non-Windows Operating System specific updates can still be controlled from somewhere else and only Windows-Operating System specific updates have been moved to new Settings window?

Comment: also that tool seems good, but is there English only version of it...I mean I am not able to understand the stuff on its UI

Comment: for example I am not able to find update status of some of Microsoft products that I installed explicitly...It just shows the updates of Windows built in prodcuts like Defender, OS Security update, Malicious Software removal tool, but nothing about say Office updates and others...I feel English language in user interface will help a lot.

Comment: "you have no control over what it installs" - You can schedule when the updates are installed.  You can also defer updates in Professional.  Home and Professional updates are indeed mandatory though.

Comment: You can defer only for a limited time, eventually they install. basically you have no real control.

Answer (score -3):

Control Panel > All control Panel Items> Windows Update.

I get to the control panel all panel items by right clicking the "Window" Icon on bottom left portion of screen and selecting control panel. Windows update is very last item on list.

Comment: If you do not have Admin privileges, some updates will require Admin log on to complete.

Comment: I can't find this option in Windows 10. I suspect R. Otero was talking about an older Windows version.