# System corruption due to windows 10 updates

Tags: windows-10

This is driving me crazy.  I've set the updates to "notify to install" but that doesn't seem to do squat; it still forces the patches to install.  I want to still be notified / nagged to install the updates so I don't want to disable the windows update service.

The problem is that my computer is a development computer. Windows update is not shutting down my computer cleanly.  Every stinking time it corrupts several databases running in MSSQL on my local box and now I just discovered that it corrupted a couple of hyper-v windows 7 sessions I use for support and testing.  Repairing the DBs after the forced update and reboot is causing a LOT of lost time and now with these hyper-v sessions toasted; I'm looking at a couple of days down.  I can't go on like this anymore...

I saw an article about setting the connection to metered, but unfortunately it doesn't appear to work with ethernet.  Anyone else have an idea on still getting the update nag but not install?

Comment: Windows 10 Home or Windows 10 Professional?  Sounds like you should be using WSUS regardless.  This way you have 100% control when the updates are pushed out.

Comment: Windows 10 requires you install updates, even with Windows 10 Professional updates are required, you only have slightly more control over when they install ( since you can defer updates ).  The only way to have full control is to use WSUS.  You cannot defer updates with Windows 10 Home.

Comment: See my answer here...http://superuser.com/a/983535

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Windows 10 stop installing driver software automatically](http://superuser.com/questions/947706/make-windows-10-stop-installing-driver-software-automatically)