# How to keep Windows 10 from Installing printer driver Microsoft XPS Document Writer

Tags: windows-10, drivers, crash

I keep getting an error:

> Installing printer driver Microsoft XPS Document Writer failed, error
>   code 0x0, HRESULT 0x80070705.

This keeps crashing Windows 10.  I have tried many things and wasted a lot of time trying to FIX it, now I just want it to go away/not attempt it.
This was either an upgrade machine from Win 7 or Win 8 (not sure, I inherited the machine from another employee)

I have tried to uninstall/install the printer using the commonly quoted uninstall and reboot then reinstall it cycle to fix the issue (but it does not of course). SO I don't need/use it thus I simply un-installed the printer by that name.  Now, daily it logs the error above just as it did before the un-install, then by coincidence, I get a "CRITICAL_TASK_FAILED" Blue screen of death.

There are tons of tasks in task manager, but none seem related to this (at least by obvious association)

**How do I even prevent the ATTEMPT to install this driver/action?**

Comment: See my answer here.... http://superuser.com/a/983535/40928

Comment: @Moab Thanks for the suggestion however I won't be installing any third party tool from a (to me) unknown source unless I get to see the code and inspect for malicious activity.

Comment: Its safe, I use it on hundreds of PC's without issue for a year, it is the only way to control updates as Microsoft W10 has removed all ability to do so. You cannot inspect any of Microsoft's source code,,,,unfounded paranoia. Good luck.

Comment: 0x80070705 = ERROR_UNKNOWN_PRINTER_DRIVER - The printer driver is unknown