# Where to set Windows 10 to Not Download Updated Without Asking Me?

Tags: windows-10

I can't figure out where to set windows 10 to not download and install updates automatically.  I don't want windows 10 to do either without my permission.  It seems the only option is whether to "notify to schedule restart".

[image]

Comment: This was one of the big controversies about Windows 10. I don't think there is any way (at least any _supported_ way) to block updates.

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer.  Very heavy handed.

Comment: You can always disable the Windows Update service.

Comment: @PeterKellner - How is keeping you updated "heavy handed"

Comment: See my answer here.... http://superuser.com/a/983535/40928

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not apply to Windows 10 HOME edition. Windows 10 Home edition cannot disable automatic updates by any supported means.

Open regedit, delete everything in this:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU`

Create these 4 values (values are hexadecimal, not decimal)

```
REG_DWORD "NoAutoUpdate" = 0x00000000
REG_DWORD "AUOptions" = 0x00000002 
REG_DWORD "ScheduledInstallDay" = 0x00000000
REG_DWORD "ScheduledInstallTime" = 0x00000003
```

For HOME edition you can set your internet connection to a "metered connection" and disable updating on metered connections. Then you only have to switch the connection's metered switch to Stop/Start automatic updates. You will still receive notification of updates being available.