# Prevent a driver from reinstalling itself in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have an HP laptop that has an AMD Radeon HD 8400 R3 graphics driver that causes the mouse to lag. When you uninstall it and use the Microsoft Basic Driver it works fine.

The things I tried are:

- Blocking hardware ID and driver updates in Regedit
- Uninstalling the driver
- Going to Control Panel and setting driver updates to No
- Windows 10 Update Hider tool
- Older driver version
- The driver from HPs site
- reinstalled Windows 10

This is getting annoying. I can't find anything else on how to stop the computer from automatically reinstalling the driver. Whenever I restart the computer, the driver comes back. It's so annoying, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This post "[Make Windows 10 stop installing driver software automatically](https://superuser.com/questions/947706/make-windows-10-stop-installing-driver-software-automatically)" seems similar with your requirement. You can check and see if it also works for you.

Comment: I've tried that, but no luck with it.