# How can i get only the updates to march 2021 in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, updates

is there a way to install only all updates to march 2021 in win10 ?
I need that cause the software i want to play on it cause a problem after the march.

Comment: You would have to prevent all updates until the end of time, much easier to diagnose the problems caused by the installation of cumulative updates after March than to prevent all updates forever (unrealistic for many reasons)

Comment: You can pull the individual KBs from the [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=kb) directly _(there's also a GUI program that can be used but can't remember the name)_, however, it's likely only one or two updates are causing the issue, not every one after March, and the only way to truly fix the issue is the game developer needs to issue a patch _(this is a common issue amongst game developers)_

Comment: See my answer here, this is a windows update utility to see and install only the updates yous wish.>>>https://superuser.com/questions/947706/make-windows-10-stop-installing-driver-software-automatically/983535#983535