# The simplest way to prevent windows 10 from auto-installing updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I am really, really annoyed with how Windows 10 automatically installs updates. This is outrageous. Numerous times so far I have ended with some of my work lost due to automatic reboot after downloading updates. I would like to ask if any of you tried preventing W10 from auto-installing stuff ? I've tried setting my conn as metered, but it still downloads "essential" updates. I've tried setting up my antivirus software firewall, but it obviously ignores these rules.

Another thing I can think about is to install firewall on my home router, but perhaps there's something more obvious that would work ?

Comment: Is that Home or Pro?

Comment: It's a pro version.

Comment: Disconnect your machine from the internet, that's the simplest solution. Get into the habit of regularly saving your work, make use of the built in features to delay updates and don't ignore informational messages about updates. In addition there are various GPO settings to influence updating.

Comment: See this to gain full control of windows updates>>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/947706/make-windows-10-stop-installing-driver-software-automatically/983535#983535

Comment: @Seth: With all due respect: that's not a solution at all. I do ignore updates because I don't want windows to install random stuff whenever they want. I DO know what I'm doing by ignoring these updates. I would only install updates if they were required by my AV software.

Comment: @Moab : Looks pretty interesting, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stopping all automatic updates Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10). *I am not actually asking by the way[.](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10)* This is absolutely without a doubt a duplicate of multiple existing questions.

Comment: @zbro you asked for the simple/easy solution. There it is regardless of what you think of it. If you are that highly opinonated about updates use a different system or a get a VL with enterprise support to have more granular management. That's what you can easily do. Everything else is going to be more complex and harder to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix the auto update issue is to set Hours of Operation.   Set Hours so that updates are done in Off Hours.

There is no need for Windows to restart in the middle of your work and using Off Hours prevents this.

I do this and Windows 10 does not restart in the middle of my work.

If you need to, updates can be paused (will not install) for 7 days. That may be helpful to you so that you can schedule time for updates.

[image: Hours of Operation]

Comment: That's not really the solution. I don't want to install any updates at all without my permission. Using mechanism you write you will end up having these updates installed eventually (windows will just skip asking you about proper time eventually).

Comment: Windows 10 newest version will always update. You can control the restart but you cannot turn off updates. That is why the Off Hours is the best approach.

Comment: @zbro - There is a automatic task, provided in an answer to the known duplicate, that explains how to exploit activity hours to prevent automatic Windows Updates from being installed. However, you really are fighting something that has been true, for nearly a decade.  Windows Updates are not required, and eventually will be installed, the best you can do is prevent the automatic reboot and perform it yourself.