# How to disable automatic updating of Windows 10 pro?

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, automatic-update

Today i install windows 10. All features is better. But i can not find the way to disable windows automatic update. In windows 8.1 or lower versions have a option to disable automatic update or updating Manually.

But in windows 10,i didn't find the update option in control panel.

> In settings >> updates.

I found no option to disable automatic updates. So how can i disable automatic updating???

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-automatic-updates-windows-10 There are good answers placed at this location

Answer (score 0):

go to settings, update & recovery .
to disable update, go to services, find windows update, disable it there.