# Have I managed to disable automatic updates on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I've already asked how to do this, but I was shunted to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-automatic-updates-windows-10), which I personally didn't find helpful, because I was already aware of the options presented and their limitations. The closest option to what I wanted was the "defer upgrades" option, but Windows says it will not defer certain updates, and only for a certain amount of time. So, I resolved myself to look for an answer myself, and I **think** I might have found one. Could anyone verify for me that this will work?

I ran the Edit Group Policy program, navigated to `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Update`, and changed the setting labeled `Configure Automatic Updates`. I changed this to option 2, labelled:

> 2 = Notify before downloading and installing any updates. When Windows finds updates that apply to this computer, users will be notified that updates are ready to be downloaded. After going to Windows Update, users can download and install any available updates.

It would appear that this is exactly what I want, but I have been told now multiple times that it's impossible in Windows 10. I'm also not too familiar with Group Policy, although from looking at its Wikipedia page, it apparently will be enforced on single computers. Could someone verify for me that this will or will not work?

Comment: No, eventually it will install the updates, you have to break windows updates in order to prevent it from downloading and installing updates. It really sucks that Microsoft has changed the WU behavior.

Comment: @Moab: Why do they have this option in group policy if the OS will just ignore it?

Comment: It works for a while but eventually the updates get installed [because the 'never" option is not there.](https://4sysops.com/archives/disable-windows-update-in-windows-10/#with-group-policy)

Comment: @Moab: Thank you for your help and attention, but from my understanding of the article you've linked to, the issue is that it *checks* for updates (and you can't stop it doing that through group policy), but it doesn't ever *download* or install updates until the user permits it. I have no practical issue with Windows checking for updates, I just wanted to control precisely when it downloads and installs updates. Do you have any other sources that say the group policy won't act as advertised?

Comment: Time will tell if your system updates itself in the future, disregarding the GP setting. All I have read says it will eventually install updates.

Comment: alwbsok, did you ever try that option?  How did it work for you?

Comment: @jk7 It worked! My computer pestered me every day, but the update history showed only Windows Defender updates, which I seem to remember allowing. The pestering was seriously annoying though! It would put up a window that you couldn't close or alt-tab away from (no matter what you were doing) with one option: "Install Updates". But, if you pressed it, it would take you to the update settings; it wouldn't force you to update.