# How to stop Unwanted Updates and Unwanted Bandwidth access in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, bandwidth

I just upgraded windows 7 to windows 10. It was looking fine and working good. But comparing to windows 7, it was accessing more bandwidth. I have only low data plan, but Windows 10 accessing more data.

In windows 7, I can disable automatic updates. That too windows 7 not consuming more data bandwidth. But I can't disable the updates in Windows 10.

So, Please anyone let me know how to stop windows 10 from unwanted bandwidth access, like auto update, automatic apps update and automatic driver updates...

Comment: What version of Windows 10 do you have? What kind of internet connection do you have?

Comment: give a look of this http://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10/963753#963753

Comment: and some of that is covered here http://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-automatic-updates-windows-10?rq=1  and links.  Disabling the services themselves that take bandwidth just seems so easy, and works on all editions, I really do not understand why that method isnt fast & easy, autoruns program still works in win10?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 3):

There are ways to disable Windows 10 updates by adjusting services and using Group Policy. If you have the Professional version of Windows 10, this may be a viable option, though it's important to run a full update once in awhile, when you have the bandwidth. This is explained in great detail in [this article](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/turn-off-windows-update-in-windows-10), namely:

> Via Control Panel > Administrative Tools, you can access Services. In the Services window, scroll down to Windows Update and turn off the process. To turn it off, right-click on the process, click on Properties and select Disabled. That will take care of Windows Updates not being installed on your machine.

And

> Setting your network connection to ‘Metered’, can also stop Windows 10 from automatically downloading the Updates. You can do it as follows – Settings app > Network & Internet > WiFi > Advanced options. Move slider to On position for Set as metered connection. See how to set Metered Connection in Windows 10.

For Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise with access to Group Policy:

> If your version of Windows 10 has Group Policy, you can also change some settings using the Group Policy Editor. Run gpedit and navigate to the following policy setting:
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update.
>
> On the right-side, double-click on Configure Automatic Updates and change its settings to suit your requirements.

I hope this is able to help. It may be easier than the alternative of port/connection filtering. If you want to run updates on your own time, without re-enabling the update service, you should be able to find some handy powershell or batch scripts for this purpose in the MSDN community.

Comment: But I'm using windows 10 Home.

Comment: That does make it a little bit more difficult, but you can still set up metered connection preferences and completely disable the update service. To open services, go to the "Run..." menu and type services.msc. When disabling Windows Update, make sure you go into the other tabs and check that it will not try to restart the service on failure. All of these options, other than Group Policy, are available on Home.

Comment: Is there is any options like updates only on Wi-fi.?

Comment: I don't believe so. It's hard enough to adjust the settings in the first place. You could manually change your metered connections options when using Wi-Fi. However, if you wanted that to be automated, my guess is that you'd need to write a script for it. Unfortunately I'm not knowledgeable enough with powershell to suggest anything.

Comment: Thank you bro..! I think metered connection will be work..! I'll try that..!