# How to stop "Get Updates" prompt?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

My computer [no longer randomly reboots itself](https://superuser.com/q/957267/5106), but now I get these full screen "Get Updates" prompts from Windows 10, which are particularly annoying when it minimizes a game I'm playing to inform me that I really need to install these useless updates right this second.

Is there a way to disable these full-screen prompts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of "Updates are available" message in Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/972038/how-to-get-rid-of-updates-are-available-message-in-windows-10)