# Enable recommended updates in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I've seen enough websites & posts about changing the automatic update settings for Windows 10, but I've not seen any post or website talk about enabling or disabling recommended updates (like you could on Windows 7).

Is there a way to enable (or disable) the recommended updates in windows 10?

Comment: there is no such option. Only to set the download /setup to notify: http://superuser.com/a/948069/174557

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

1. Click start menu
2. Options
3. Security & Updates
4. Windows Updates
5. Advanced Options
6. Check Defer Upgrades

Comment: This only works if you have Windows 10 Professional or Windows 10 Enterprise/Education

Comment: Do not do this, defer updates pauses feature updates (the big updates) for around 6 months. It does not show recommended updates.