# How to disable a single update in windows update (Win10)

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, windows-10, windows-update

I have to disable A SINGLE update in windows 10, which is my video card, every freaking time it updates it i'll have BLUE SCREEN: THREAD_STUCK_IN_DEVICE_DRIVER, because the driver avaiable for windows update for the video card: AMD HD 7730m from DELL INSPIRON 15R SE (Inspiron 7520) doesn't work.

My video card is currently disabled, so I don't get any blue screen for it, but before disabling it I erase the full driver using Guru3D.com (which fully erases a video card driver), and after it I disable it.

But windows update always recognizes it even tho its disabled and gives me the update, so sometime it will install and give me blue screen, how can I fix this? I tried using a driver that works but its not the updated driver, its a windows 8.1 version that works in win10, but windows recognizes it as old and tries to update it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping all automatic updates windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10)

Comment: The proposed duplicate is about stopping all updates.  This question is about selectively stopping just one.

Comment: @fixer1234 **no**, I posted a link to the MS troubleshooter to also stop single updates/drivers

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid but it seems at it is not possible to disable windows update in any way shape or form for users this time around.

This is all you can do as a user:

http://www.howtogeek.com/224471/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-downloading-updates/

Whish you that your drivers will be fixed soon by WU!

Answer (score -1):

I believe the following may help, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930

I find it strange that they provide the option to insert a link but you say that it can be broke?.. Seems to work for me if I click on it, but anyway search for KB3073930

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you think will happen to the link if MS move the content? How useful is a 404 not found?

Comment: You think that someone can't google it? In fact I google'd it, need I say more.

Comment: If you think someone hasn't put enough research effort into the question then don't answer it. If you do answer, it's your job to make sure the answer is quality.