# Windows 10: Configure Windows Update to search updates BUT ask before downloading/installing

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

My Windows 7 SP1 includes an option inside the **Windows Update** configuration to search for updates, but **allow me to select** if I want to download and/or install them.

I have not been able to locate such option on **Windows 10**.
**Where** is it, or how could I make such change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping all automatic updates windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10)

Comment: does not answer the question "allow me to select if I want to download and/or install them." which cannot be done in W10.

Comment: @Moab sure. I get a toast notification and when I want I can open the setting app and click on a button to start download/install the updates when I want it, not when MS forces me to do it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 more details please.

Comment: @Moab which details? Select "select Notify for download and notify for install" does what he wants. see my answer in the duplicate link