# Can I permanently block an update (non-driver) that will not install on my machine on Win10 pro?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have an update to Visual Studio 2010 that will NOT update and has failed hundreds of times. Manually installing it also fails, and no source has been found for manually getting this very old patch to install on Windows 10. I believe the problem is that Microsoft simply hasn't re-tested KB2890573 at all and it doesn't install on Win10 ver 1511 at all, anymore.

I do not want to use the MS utility that will postpone this update for a while. I want to permanently block it so it does not appear in the windows update list ever again.

[image]

Comment: have you tried this? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930 http://superuser.com/a/948069/174557

Comment: Yes, that's why I said I want to permanently (not temporarily) block an update.  If there IS a way to do this, then it's not the same as turning ALL updates off, or blocking a single update TEMPORARILY.  It seems Microsoft didn't think this through, as usual.

Comment: there is no other official way. Use this 3rd party tool instead: http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/windows-update-minitool.380535/

Comment: That seems like it should be the answer.  Its ok to convert to answer.

Comment: I posted it as answer

Comment: does the tool work? If yes, mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other official way to permanently block updates except the Troubleshooter from [KB3073930](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930).

There is a 3rd party tool called [Windows Update MiniTool](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/windows-update-minitool.380535/) which allows to select which updates can be installed and allows to block updates like you could in former Windows versions.

[image]

> An alternative to the standard Windows Update What you can do: • Check
>   for updates 
>  • Download updates
>  • Installing Updates
>  •
>   Deleting installed updates
>  • **Hiding unwanted updates**
>  • Get
>   direct links to the *.cab / *.Exe / *.Psf update files • View update
>   history
>  • Configure Automatic Updates
>  • This tool is like the
>   external powershell module PSWindowsUpdate, but much more advanced and
>   user-friendly features
>  • The tool relies and use same WU
>   infrastructure, all downloading are through WU it's not a
>   downloader