# Windows 10 Update shows unwanted Language Packs

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, language-pack

I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise.

When I go to Windows Update, I get some Updates that I would like to install and about 100 Language Packs that I have neither requested nor want to install.

They are all in the form of `Lang Pack (Language Features) Feature On Demand for X64 [af-ZA]`.

I have already looked under "Language" in the Control Panel but there is just German (my main Windows Language).

How can I get rid of these unwanted Language Packs?
[image: Windows Update]

Comment: try this 3rd party tool to hide the updates: http://superuser.com/a/1014251/174557

Comment: The tool did not find the Language Pack Updates (I tried all possible search combinations).

Comment: post a picture of what you see. I think you look into the Feature Window and not into the WindowsUpdate Window

Comment: I added the picture

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that I found to remove a language pack from Windows 10 is to open an elevated prompt (I used PowerShell) and use `lpksetup.exe /u` followed by the language code, such as `fr-fr` (French). Example: `lpksetup.exe /u fr-fr` The process took several minutes to complete on a computer with an SSD, and was handy in that it provided a progress bar window. This worked for me on Windows 10.14393

*Further Reference for LPKSETUP Method*
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-and-remove-language-packs-on-a-running-windows-installation

FYI: There is documentation of an online DISM method using `/Remove-Capability`, but this generated error 87 for me.

*Further Reference of DISM Method*
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/features-on-demand-v2--capabilities