# Avoid Windows 10 Anniversary edition automated restart on updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, reboot

Since the most recent big Windows anniversary update, the previous option to disable automated reboots on Windows Updates has stopped working.
The system gives you the option to set "active hours", but only 12 hours may be set. I'm not against rebooting, but I want it fully on my terms, manually. Is there a way since the anniversary update to disable automated reboot?

Comment: `Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update and then click the Advanced options button. In the drop-down box, switch the setting to “Notify to schedule restart.” ` - does not work any longer?

Comment: That option does no longer exist on my system.

Comment: use this tool from my answer to control WU: http://superuser.com/a/948069/174557

Comment: You may try this http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-permanently-stop-windows-10-reboots-after-installing-updates/

Comment: @random - NOT a duplicate. The question here is about _Windows 10 Anniversary Update_, the suspected duplicate is for _pre-Anniversary Update_. Both solution described in the suspected duplicate _do no longer exist after Windows Anniversary Update_