# What options are available for managing security updates on the various Win 10 service branches?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I've spent a lot of time reading through the documentation around the service branch options for Windows 10 and I have a reasonably good understanding around how feature upgrades are managed and the options administrators have.

Current Branch (CB) - Upgrades installed immediately upon release
Current Branch for Business (CBB) - Upgrades delayed for ~4 months and can be deferred by up to another 8 months.
Long Term Service Branch (LTSB) - Upgrades can be deferred indefinitely.

What I don't understand is how service updates (security updates, etc..., not upgrades) are handled.  They'll obviously be installed immediately on the CB, but I can't find anything concrete on how long they can be deferred (if at all) on the other 2 branches.

What little I've seen indicates that it might be dependent on the CM tool you use.  When on the CBB, Windows Update gives you an option to defer updates for up to 4 weeks, but you might have more options for Windows Update Server, SCCM, or another CM.

If anyone could help clear up the options for security updates on the CBB or LTSB branches, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only way to have complete control over when a security udpate is installed is to use WSUS.

Answer (score 0):

Normal Updates (those cumulative Updates) which fix security issues and fix bugs are installed immediately. There is no official way to delay them. Here you have to use a 3rd party tool [Windows Update MiniTool](https://superuser.com/a/948069/174557) to control which updates get installed.

Comment: You can also delay them by using WSUS in general.  WSUSOffline and Windows Update MiniTool both work on the same underline principle.