# Windows Update frozen bootloop, can't remove update using DISM

Tags: windows-10, freeze, windows-update, dism

- **OS:** Windows 10 Pro x64 14393.187
- **PC:** Asus M51AC-FR034S
- **Hardware:** Intel Core i7 4770S; Asus GTX 760; 16GB DDR3 1333MHz
- **Storage:** 1TB HDD; 240GB SSD (Samsung 850 Evo)

After 35 days of uptime, fearing what would happen if I rebooted my computer (I've got problems with WU in the past), I decided to give Windows Update a try and finally install those updates (can't remember which KB) it has been trying to install for 3 months. I rebooted my computer, and then it was showing "Rebooting..." and then the screen froze. So I rebooted the PC, it showed "Installing updates..." and then it froze. I rebooted it again, and then it showed "Couldn't install updates. Undoing changes..." and then it froze. Same when booting in Safe Mode. So I tried launching a repair command prompt from the PE environment, to list the installed updates using `dism /image:d:\windows /get-packages` and I got this:

```
Identité du package : Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.953.1.2
État : Installation en attente
Type de version : Security Update
Heure d’installation : 26/03/2017 13:48

L’opération a réussi.
```

("Installation en attente" meaning "Installation pending")

So I ran `dism /image:d:\windows /remove-package /packagename:[longname]`:

```
Traitement de 1 sur 1 - Suppression du package Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.953.1.2
[==========================100.0%==========================]
Une erreur s’est produite - Package_for_RollupFix Erreur : 0x80070bc9

Erreur : 3017

Échec de l’opération demandée. Il est nécessaire de redémarrer le système pour restaurer les modifications apportées.

Le fichier journal DISM se trouve à l’emplacement X:\windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

- Is it possible to remove that update?

  - If DISM really can't work, is it possible to remove it manually (remove some files, change some registry values) ?
- Preferrably without reinstalling Windows?

**EDIT:** Here is the [DISM.log file](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/45478c444e64b6579de710c0ffd08ba1) (the relevant errors are near lines 2232 and 2312).

**EDIT 2:** `dism [...] /scanhealth` did not find any errors.

**EDIT 3:** When I try to boot into Windows, it shows the "undoing changes" screen, and then the system freezes - screen is frozen, mouse pointer is not visible, num/caps/scroll lock is unresponsive, and I don't have any HDD activity LED. Also, I tried letting the PC work over night (maybe it would un-freeze automagically at some time), but after 19 hours it hasn't changed.

**EDIT 4:** Following Ramhound's advice, I tried to uninstall previous updates (the 14393.*** ones) but I noticed that DISM is always stuck at 10.0% and simply stays there, while writing to its log file:

```
2017-03-27 19:08:34, Error                 CSI    00001800 (F) Current pending rollback transaction content precludes other operations; reboot to complete rollback.[gle=0x80004005]
2017-03-27 19:08:34, Error                 CSI    00001801 (F) HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FAIL_REBOOT_REQUIRED) #13918885# from Windows::COM::CComponentStore::InternalTransact(...)[gle=0x80070bc9]
2017-03-27 19:08:34, Error                 CSI    00001802@2017/3/27:17:08:34.745 (F) onecore\base\wcp\componentstore\com\store.cpp(4970): Error HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FAIL_REBOOT_REQUIRED) originated in function Windows::COM::CComponentStore::InternalTransact expression: HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(3017L)
[gle=0x80004005]
2017-03-27 19:08:34, Info                  CBS    Added X:\windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log to WER report.
2017-03-27 19:08:34, Info                  CBS    Failed to create filter driver list file. [HRESULT = 0x80070003 - ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]
2017-03-27 19:08:34, Info                  CBS    Failed to submit the Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x8007053d - ERROR_SERVER_DISABLED]
2017-03-27 19:08:34, Error                 CSI    00001803 (F) HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FAIL_REBOOT_REQUIRED) #13918883# from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction::ICSITransaction2_Analyze(Flags = 0, riid = {f4d9decb-0250-4ad4-9500-85c7f2f281ec}, ppUnk = NULL, disp = 0)[gle=0x80070bc9]
2017-03-27 19:08:34, Info                  CBS    Failed to get transaction analysis. [HRESULT = 0x80070bc9 - ERROR_FAIL_REBOOT_REQUIRED]
2017-03-27 19:08:34, Info                  CBS    Failed to get inventory. [HRESULT = 0x80070bc9 - ERROR_FAIL_REBOOT_REQUIRED]
2017-03-27 19:08:34, Info                  CSI    00001804@2017/3/27:17:08:34.747 CSI Transaction @0xd7d0d80 destroyed
2017-03-27 19:08:34, Info                  CBS    Failed to get CSI Inventory [HRESULT = 0x80070bc9 - ERROR_FAIL_REBOOT_REQUIRED]
2017-03-27 19:08:34, Info                  CBS    Failed to get component state. [HRESULT = 0x80070bc9 - ERROR_FAIL_REBOOT_REQUIRED]
2017-03-27 19:08:34, Info                  CBS    Plan: Package: Package_1378_for_KB3213986~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.1, Update: 3213986-2798_neutral, current: Absent, pending: Default, start: Absent, applicable: Absent, targeted: Absent, limit: Absent, selected: Default
2017-03-27 19:08:34, Info                  CBS    Plan: Force applicability state to absent due to absent limit state on package: Package_1379_for_KB3213986~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.1
2017-03-27 19:08:34, Info                  CBS    Plan: Package: Package_1379_for_KB3213986~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.1, current: Staged, pending: Default, start: Staged, applicable: Absent, targeted: Absent, limit: Absent
2017-03-27 19:08:34, Info                  CSI    00001805 Transaction merge required, do-not-merge flag passed.
2017-03-27 19:08:34, Info                  CSI    00001806@2017/3/27:17:08:34.750 CSI Transaction @0xadf26b0 initialized for deployment engine {d16d444c-56d8-11d5-882d-0080c847b195} with flags 00000002 and client id 'TI5.3364_3202296:879/'
```

Every 2 or 3 seconds (here it's 19:08:34, the previous one was 31 and the next one 36), and it keeps writing the same thing over and over.

**EDIT 5:** I removed C:\Windows\WinSxS\pending.xml and now it got to the lock screen! Well, actually, it got to the lock screen but it stayed there. I think I fixed the update problem, but not the freeze problem. I took my stopwatch, and it seems the system freezes 5 seconds (+ or - 1 second) after the boot screen disappears, no matter if in Safe Mode (which, by the way, stays on a black screen). Before I deleted the file, Windows was freezing on an update screen, now it's freezing on the login screen. I restarted multiple times, sometimes I'm fast enough to press a key and hide the lock screen, but not fast enough to type my password and log in, before it freezes.

**EDIT 6:** When booting into "Safe Mode with Networking" (the normal Safe Mode boots directly to normal), I managed to get a BSOD with the error WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR. Unfortunately, after 30 minutes, it was still at 0%, and as usual, it didn't create a dump file.

Comment: not all updates can be uninstalled from image. if you can boot in windows [use the tool from my answer](https://superuser.com/a/948069/174557) to hide the update.

Comment: @magicandre1981 No, as I said, every time I try to boot into Windows it shows the screen saying that it's undoing the changes, and then the screen freezes (the progress bar freezes too, and everything is unresponsive).

Comment: ok, boot again to recovery option and run **DISM /image:D:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions** to revert the pending changes.

Comment: You need to figure which KB it is trying to install.  KB4013429 is 14393.953, but that doesn't make sense, if your system has been trying to  install it the "last couple months" because KB4013429 was released on 3/14/2017

Comment: @magicandre1981 It says "Reverting pending actions..." and then "Error: 0x8000ffff"

Comment: @Ramhound I've been on 14393.953 for a couple of months (at least 3 or 4 months), because it was trying to install the new Insider build (and some other minor updates), but every time it failed (every time it got to the "Upgrading Windows" screen, but froze, then I restarted and it un-did the changes). The only difference is that this time, it couldn't undo the changes.

Comment: @zdimension - **That is literally not possible.**  `14393.953` was released this month and is for 1607.  You might have been on ealier build of 14393, for a couple months, but **not the current build.**

Comment: @Ramhound You're right. Sorry, I only remembered 14393 and I thought 953 was the second number, but I had a look in the registry and the system appears to be 14393.187. But as you said it's weird, since I've been unable to update for months, and this update is recent. If it failed for other updates, I guess the problem must come from WU itself, but it'd be strange since I managed to install other "minor" updates since then.

Comment: Build `14393.187` is around 6+ months old.  `KB3189866` ( i.e. `14393.187`) was republished as `KB3193494` with build `14393.189` due to an error.  The fact you have `14393.187` and not `14393.189`, tells me you need to uninstall `KB3189866` and then install `KB3193494`, to solve your problem.

Comment: You should try and install, [KB3193494](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3193494), and see if you can manually push your installation to `14393.189`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56113/discussion-between-zdimension-and-ramhound).

Comment: @Ramhound See the DISM log in the latest edit, it seems to be a driver issue

Comment: I forget what the mode is called, but I believe there is still an option, to have Windows request confirmation for every driver it should load.  You could also in theory, use the command prompt within WinRE, to load the registry hive and remove all instances of the problem driver.

Comment: 0x8000ffff = E_UNEXPECTED = Catastrophic failure. so this error code is not helpful. Get the 1703 ISO and reinstall Windows from scratch and do backups now each month before installing a new update. http://winaero.com/blog/windows-10-creators-update-rtm-build-15063-official-iso-images/

Comment: WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR = HW issue (cpu damaged)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved my problem!

The solution was completely unrelated to anything I've said previously!

I simply copied everything in the `C:\Windows\system32\config\RegBack` folder (which was created automatically before the update) to `C:\Windows\system32\config`, and everything worked correctly.

If I have the time, I will try to compare the two registry hives to see what changed.