# Windows only boots if Tcpip driver is disabled

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, drivers, freeze

- **OS:** Windows 10 Pro x64 14393.187
- **PC:** Asus M51AC-FR034S
- **Hardware:** Intel Core i7 4770S; Asus GTX 760; 16GB DDR3 1333MHz
- **Storage:** 1TB HDD; 240GB SSD (Samsung 850 Evo)

While trying to solve [my other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1192539/windows-update-frozen-bootloop-cant-remove-update-using-dism), I noticed that if I disabled the Tcpip driver (i.e. set `HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Tcpip\Start` to 4); then the system would boot (almost) correctly, and the freeze problem isn't present anymore, which means I can finally log in (by almost I mean that I still can't log in completely, I'm getting a black screen since explorer.exe for some reason doesn't want to start, but that's another problem).

At first I thought it was really a hardware problem, but it seems that it isn't, since a Windows 10 live ISO works perfectly, and my Ubuntu dual-boot too, so it must come from Windows itself.

I've tried to repair the system using sfc and dism, but it didn't have any effect. Whenever I enable the driver, the system becomes unable to boot (technically it boots, but it freezes on the login screen).

Useful to note that occasionally I get a BSOD (if the driver is enabled and I boot in Safe Mode with Networking) but it stays at 0% and never creates a dump file.

I've had this issue in the past, but the last time it happened simply disabling the Ethernet network adapter, rebooting and enabling it solved the problem. Now, I can't disable it because I need the Tcpip driver to be enabled to make changes to the network settings.

Is it possible to fix that problem, without reinstalling Windows? Also, I have a PCIe Wi-Fi card, maybe I could use it instead of the Ethernet one if it's possible to re-enable the Tcpip driver?

Comment: Your Windows installation is several (6+) months old.  You should download the 1703 ISO and update your installation.  You might solve your problem by doing so.  You still need to get rid of the .187 KB and install .189, as I said before, .187 is the source of your problem there is a reason it was pulled

Comment: @Ramhound I can't remove that update, DISM just stays there and write stuff to the log (see the other thread). Also I just download the latest ISO (15058 IIRC) and tried to run the setup.exe file, but once launched, it either doesn't show anything, or show the Windows logo for a few seconds and then says that it can't install and that I must reboot my PC (and of course rebooting doesn't change anything).

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem!

The solution was completely unrelated to anything I've said previously!

I simply copied everything in the `C:\Windows\system32\config\RegBack` folder (which was created automatically before the update) to `C:\Windows\system32\config`, and everything worked correctly.

If I have the time, I will try to compare the two registry hives to see what changed.