# How to stop Win10 from rebooting without consent?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I just lost 3 days worth of processing because win10 decided that the update was more important and rebooted the system without asking, notification or warning.

Is there a way to turn this ‘feature’ off for good?

Scheduling is not an option, since it will restart regardless.

Comment: Not a direct answer but you need to fix your processing so that it does not lose its information because of a reboot. Computers are not reliable (unblkess you have a Tandem etc)

Comment: Which build are you running? They seem to significantly differ in aggressiveness.

Comment: You can control the reboot times to some extent by setting the active hours in Windows Update. Or you can disable automatic updates altogether by configuring your internet connection as metered.

Comment: @AFH configuring your internet as metered will have some unwanted sideeffects, such as outlook not syncing automatically either. It is easier to simply disable the Windows Update services instead.

Comment: @grawity Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.192]

Comment: In the duplicate, look for the answer about disabling the Windows Update services. It will definitely work and you can even script this so you can turn it on and off on the fly.

Comment: @LPChip - I don't use Outlook, so I haven't noticed this. I use it because it is very easy to turn off and on, but thanks for the warning, and pausing updates in your reference is probably a better option in this instance.

Comment: @LPChip Thanks! I have followed https://superuser.com/a/1274001/167535

Comment: @Mark, not every algorithm can be started/restarted arbitrarily

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate: I suggested stopping updates as a work-round, but the ideal would be to allow the update process to continue, while disabling unattended reboot. I don't know of a way to achieve this, but it may be possible with a registry patch. You may want to experiment with changing settings in `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Update` the next time a restart is pending (back up first, of course), but I don't know what all the entries mean, so you'll be on your own. If you find a solution, post your own answer: a lot of us will be grateful.