# Stop Windows 10 Professional 1709 from rebooting after update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, reboot

Does anyone have a proven way to stop Windows from rebooting after it does an update. My machine is on all the time and I would like to chose when to reboot it as the reboots do not save things and recover well.

I have done some Google Fu and searches on SO, but nothing seems to work for 1709. Anyone got a solution?

Comment: You can either schedule when the updates will be installed, which I believe, allows you to schedule it within 48-72 hours (and later change it again) or configure your activity hours.  Worth pointing out that with 1709 Windows will attempt to restore your applications to the same state after a reboot unless you have taken steps to prevent that from happening. All of this can be done within the Settings application.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah so every 2 days I have to keep remember to defer it.  Not a great solution. I often go a few weeks before doing updates because there are times when the updates break the machine eg. MS pulling the AMD Spectre/Mektdown update after it bricks the machine. And no Windows does NOT restore the machine to the same state. I know this from *painful* experience. So while I appreciate your suggestions these are still just a half work around to stopping it doing it. And no turning off updates is not a sensible answer either.

Comment: If your programs are not being restored to the same state then you are not running Windows 10 Version 1709.  My comment about scheduling the update to be installed was more about your immediate need for the system, not weeks worth of need.  *Please be a good member of the internet community and patch your system*  Based on my knowledge on the subject, the `Spectre Meltdown` patched was only pulled for AMD systems not Intel systems.

Comment: @Ramhound "...not running..." You are missing the point. The only way that an application recovers well if is it supports it. So lets take something like Sql Server Management Studio. Leave it open and then let Windows restart your machine. See if it opens up SSMS the way you left it. It won't. And that is an application that MS wrote.  ".....was only pulled for AMD...." yep so not only was it automatically pulled but then MS rebooted the machine and guess what it does not boot up. So hence my question to stop the idiocy of it happening automagically.

Comment: Maybe some of this could help? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-restart

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping all automatic updates windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10)