# Stop Windows 10 OS Updates

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, auto-updates

I have a machine with a warm boot issue, and Windows 10 installed on it. That issue being when updates are applied and the OS attempts to reboot itself it fails. If I manually boot it is fine.....fix for this at the machine/source of the problem, is apparently unsupported.

Due to this I need to prevent Windows 10 from OS updates (not Windows Updates because I have disabled them both in UI and Registry), however when there is a Windows OS Update, this doesn't seem to prevent that from happening. Through the UI mechanisms you can schedule for later, wait an hour, etc but there no option where the user can simply elect to not install the update.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening, sort of just not using pc?

Comment: Disable the Windows Update service and only enable it when you are prepared to update

Comment: I have disabled Windows Update via the registry, deactivate on startup, and through Powershell listener to watch the service and if it starts up, stop it. This prevent Security/Cumulative, WD, Office, other products, etc updates from downloading and installing, but not 'new OS release type update' apparently because none of the above prevents that from taking place.

Comment: You cannot disable Windows Update through the registry on Windows 10 Home, but you can disable the service, or configure your system to use WSUS instead. Feature Updates are installed only every 6 months so easy to plan for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping all automatic updates windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10).  The minitool answer can be applied easily enough on Home, gpedit while not default, can be added to Home without much effort.  https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i

Comment: wow, came back and closed. nice. this isn't a duplicate because it isn't the same issue, you just assume that the fix is the same. ya know, perhaps it's my fault as I just worded this poorly. thanks

Comment: So edit the question.  By doing so you place it into a queue to be reopened.  You say it isn't the issue, but multiple users whom have proven themselves knowledgeable in this area indicate otherwise.  If you can clarify your question in such a way, that it is clear the existing answers do not apply to your situation, it only takes 5 people (or a single person with a gold badge) or a single moderator to reopen your question.  **Of course typically poorly worded questions are simply closed.**

Comment: If your not willing to clarify your question don’t complain about the closure.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the Pro or Home edition? I think the following is available in Pro, but may not be in Home edition.

Settings / Update & Security / Windows Update / Advanced Options / [X] Defer Upgrades

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026834/windows-10-defer-upgrades

Comment: apparently home edition; looks like perhaps that is probably the capability I was looking for and is not in this edition.

Answer (score -2):

With most editions of Windows 10, ultimate control over the machine lies not with the owner, but exclusivly with Microsoft.

This implies, that there is no way to stop Microsoft from doing whatever pleases them on your Computer, including installing whatever Software they want, unless you choose to permanently disconnect from their C&C servers, i.e. mostly disconnect from the Internet.

There exist a few hacks to mitigate this as much as possible, but none are reliable and most do not survive OS (i.e. built-in spyware) "updates".

Comment: "is no way to stop Microsoft from doing whatever pleases them on your Computer, including installing whatever Software they want" - Say what?

Comment: Aside from the obvious bias (to which I am sympathetic), there's no useful *information* here. Your main point is true of any closed-source software, and only worth mentioning in passing: most folks have already chosen their stance on that, and it's not really on-topic by itself. The only useful mention is the vague "There exist a few hacks...", which are not described.

Comment: @Ramhound Say Microsoft.

Comment: @jpaugh The information is: There is no positive answer to the OQ, as the OP has no ultimate control over his OS

Comment: @EugenRieck Sure they do, WSUS is one, disable Windows Update is another.  MS does NOT have the ability to push random software to you.  Software being part of an install image is something else entirely, even the , you can create your own image

Comment: Unsubstantiated propaganda is harmful to open source. And, certainly not in line with the spirit of StackExchange.

Comment: My first experience with the only Windows 10 Home on a laptop we circumstantislly ended up with that was preinstalled FELT much like Eugen Rieck describes.  Admittadly a friend of ours with Windows 10 Pro did not have any problems we encountered.  And most options to.manage it were not availible for the Home version (group policy namely).  While I agree it is not a informative answer with evidence included,  it's not all blasphemy either.  I spent hours trying to get rid of the bloat and  gain control.only.to restart and have much of it undone.  Win 10 Home FELT like spyware in that moment.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, https://tech.slashdot.org/story/18/02/15/1720243/hey-microsoft-stop-installing-apps-on-my-pc-without-asking seems to agree with me

Comment: That link is hardly a reliable source

Comment: @Ramhound Whoever doesn't want to believe, just needs to close his eyes