# Windows 10 "Update & Security" dialog does not appear - Updates not working

Tags: windows-10, security, windows-update

When I go to Settings and then click on "Update & security" no window/dialog appears... and the "Settings" window/dialog also disappears.

I have also not been notified of any Windows updates needing installation for about 2 months.

I should perhaps mention that I loathe Windows more than death... and for that reason I went (after installing) to some lengths to ensure that no "updates" were ever installed automatically (disabling the Windows Update service, turning off use of it "because I'm on a metered connection", all that nonsense).

Instead, what used to happen was that at the end of every month I would check (via "Update & security") for any updates which I supposedly had to install... and then I would head off to https://catalog.update.microsoft.com to pick up and download the individual update programs (usually beginning "KB...").

Actually I can run Windows Defender separately (virus and spyware protection up-to-date), so I don't have any particular need to access this "Update & Security" dialog, although it would be good if I could get it back.  Failing that, is there a way of determining from some website what downloads from catalog.update.microsoft.com I should be installing?

NB I **am** able to obtain a list of installed updates (View installed updates) present in my W10 OS.

NB googling around for solutions I seem to have found that there has been a particularly pernicious M$ "update" in April this year.  Perhaps it's good I missed out on this.

Comment: use the [WindowsUpdate Minitool](https://superuser.com/a/948069/174557) to search for new updates.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks very much...

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: er, yes, I talked about that link in my post.  Linux does not yet have useable dictation software or a couple of other things which I have to use when I'm working.  Whenever I'm not working I immediately reboot to beautiful Linux Mint.