# How do I block Windows 10 Guest VM from updating itself Linux Mint Host

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, firewall, iptables

I have windows 10 running as a guest OS in Virtual Box. As you know, this virus of an OS updates itself automatically and you can't disable this. How can I block the windows update servers from my Linux host so that it cannot waste my metered bandwidth with useless updates I don't need while at the same time being able to access the rest of the internet from within the guest OS.

Thanks!

**My question is not a duplicate. The one you refer to is about blocking windows update IN WINDOWS. I am running windows as GUEST VM and want to block the updates on the HOST Linux OS such that if I install a new windows guest I won't have to repeat the blocking process!**

Comment: I stop Windows automatic updates by classifying the internet connection as metered. There are a couple of issues, but on the whole it works quite effectively.

Comment: How do I do that? I'd rather just block it on Host level, I don't trust that POS Operating System to obey my commands.

Comment: In Windows Settings (`Win`+`i`), click on `Network & Internet`, then on `Change Connection Properties`.

Comment: SuperUser has many similar questions from the default physical install perspective.  I will let OP search and discover which to apply.  Beware that the Update tools and assumptions change, so old info is oldBeware that the built-in tools in Windows 10 only allow you to delay updates, not prevent entirely.  The flavor (Home, Pro, Workstation) matters, as does if it's connected to a domain, as does if it's using WSUS, which is far beyond the scope of work that you want to do.  MS wants Windows to update, and your best bet might be to block the ports at the host level rather than the guest level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping all automatic updates Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10)

Comment: It is not a duplicate of that. I am asking about blocking domains on THE HOST not in the GUEST OS. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: @CharisTheProgrammer Maybe you can block Microsoft’s update servers directly on the host using iptables?

Comment: @Steve how can I do that?