# Windows 10 force updates

Tags: windows

I have a computer which is currently on Windows 10 Pro.

Honestly Microsoft really annoys me how they try to force everyone to update. I have a computer that needs to be on and running 24/7 and these force updates are preventing this.

I have tried various workarounds, but Windows somehow always manages to remove my workaround and enable the updates again.

If I upgrade to Windows 10 Enterprise would I have option to permanently disable Windows updates?

Else what do you suggest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping all automatic updates Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10)

Comment: Thanks but that is an old thread and I believe most if not all of those workarounds have been patched by Microsoft already.

Comment: @BruH - All of them still work with 1809.

Comment: Just happened to me ... I need my computer and that **** update is installing itself for around a half hour by now and is at 4%. Gave me the option to remind me in an hour, ok, update now - I pressed remind me in an hour 5 times until  ifinally did "ok". So whats the difference between "Ok" and "Update Now"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that we cannot disable Windows Update Service in Windows 10. It's a policy in Microsoft. If you disable it, it will run by itself.

But there are two ways can help us to defer updates to 30 days, try the following steps:
1. Select the Start  button, then select Settings  > Update & Security  > Windows Update .
2. Under Update settings, select Advanced options.
3. From the boxes under Choose when updates are installed, select the number of days you would like to defer a feature update or a quality update. Note: If your PC is managed by an organization, you may not be able to defer updates.

1. Press Win+R to open the RUN command.
2. Type: gpedit.msc and press enter to open the Local Group Policy Editor.
3. Find: Computer Configuration> Administrative Templates> Windows Components> Windows Update> Windows Update for Business
4. Double-click the Select when Quality Updates are received policy.
5. Choose Enabled and type the days you want to defer.
6. Click Ok and Apply.

---

Yes, we can disable Automatic update in windows server 2016.
You can refer to this: [disable automatic update in windows server 2016](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/d3a2694c-32da-4158-943a-81c2904ffb3d/disable-automatic-updates-in-2016?forum=WinServerPreview)

Comment: Ok if we cannot disable it on Windows 10, I will consider to install Windows Server 2016 instead. Window server definitely has option to disable updates correct?