# Windows 10: How can I install only Patch Tuesday updates, not “C” and “D” Updates?

Tags: windows-10, updates

In case someone doesn't know, Windows has its most important and other previously tested updates on the second Tuesday of every month (Patch Tuesday, a.k.a. "B" updates). Unfortunately, they also have “C” and “D” updates on the 3rd and 4th week respectively, which contain less tested bug fixes, etc.

Here is a link describing it: [Link](https://www.howtogeek.com/398226/now-windows-10-has-c-b-and-d-updates.-what-is-microsoft-smoking/)

Obviously, I don't want to be a test subject, especially since I work on my PC, so I only want "B" patches. Unless there is a critical patch, I want to usually wait for 1-2 weeks, just in case there is a problem with the patches. But that means that if I update then I run more risks by downloading the "C” and “D” Updates.

Is there any way (maybe a tool) to select which updates to download? The only one I can think of is by manually downloading each one, which is not very convenient?

**EDIT:** Some people mention that I have to click "Check for updates" in order to receive the unwanted updates. It is my mistake that I forgot to mention that although I have not pressed it, I have the following updates pending:

```
KB2589339: March 5
KB4486553: March 1
KB4483452: Feb 15
KB4018313: Feb 12 (patch Tuesday)
KB4462174: Feb 12 (patch Tuesday)
KB4487038: Feb 12 (patch Tuesday)
```

KB4487044: Feb 12 (patch Tuesday)

As you can see, 3 of them were released later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Unless there is a critical patch, I want to usually wait for 1-2 weeks, just in case there is a problem with the patches. But that means that if I update then I run more risks by downloading the "C” and “D” Updates.

Windows 10 Professional allows you to defer quality updates for up to 30 days.  If you are worried about installing updates that have not been well tested you can defer updates to achieve this goal.

*The only problem with deferring quality updates, is if a previous update has a known issue, you will eventually get that update after 30 days instead of the current update with the resolution.  Any cumulative quality update has the potential to have a known issue like the last one for instance ([KB4482887](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4482887))*

[image]

> Is there any way (maybe a tool) to select which updates to download? The only one I can think of is by manually downloading each one, which is not very convenient?

You can configure your own WSUS environment, and only install the updates you push to your system, but that does not appear to be what you want to do.  You can also disable Windows Update entirely and install updates manually.

[If you want total control over your system, you will have to take the steps to prevent Windows Update from automatically downloading update entirely, and handle the entire process manually.](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10)

Important Relevant Questions:

- [How to *disable* automatic reboots in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10)
- [Stopping all automatic updates Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10)

Comment: I have purposefully not provided specific details on how to prevent Windows Update from downloading all Windows Updates since I believe that to be a horrible idea.

Answer (score 3):

The article that you referenced already provides the answer:

> Microsoft says C and D updates are “optional,” and Windows Update
>   won’t automatically install them on your PC.
>
> Windows Update doesn’t automatically install C and D updates on most
>   PCs. However, it does install C and D updates when you head to
>   **Settings** > **Update & Security** > **Windows Update** and click *“Check for Updates.”*
>
> [image: Check for updates]
>
> So, if you click *“Check for Updates”* in the third, fourth, or first
>   week of a month before the next B update has been released, you’ll
>   probably get a C or D update installed on your system. If you never
>   click *“Check for Updates,”* you’ll stick with the better-tested B
>   updates.

The bottom line is that if you don't manually initiate a search by utilizing the `Check for updates` button, you will get exactly what you desire: only the Patch Tuesday "B" updates will be installed automatically.

---

Source: [Now Windows 10 Has C, B, and D Updates. What is Microsoft Smoking?](https://www.howtogeek.com/398226/now-windows-10-has-c-b-and-d-updates.-what-is-microsoft-smoking/)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to disappoint you, but from [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/how-to-choose-which-updates-to-install-windows-10/1ea0fdf7-e125-451d-8299-d9c374db7c3d?auth=1) you cannot choose which updates to install, only to *uninstall*:

> We understand your concern and we will provide the assistance required to help you resolve the issue.
>
> I would like to inform you that in Windows 10 you cannot choose the
>   updates that you wish to install as all the updates are automated.
>   However you can Hide/Block the updates that you do not wish to install
>   in your computer. To do so you will have to use the tool that is
>   provided in the link below.
>
> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930
>
> Note: You will not be able to block Security patches that you receive
>   through Windows Updates

Answer (score 0):

“C” and “D” updates are released in the third and fourth weeks of the month, respectively. 
These updates just include new bug fixes and improvements for other non-security issues.
Patch Tuesday updates appearing in the second week of the month,
are suitably called "B" updates.

Windows Update will only install C and D updates when you go to
*Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update* and click “Check for Updates”.
In Microsoft’s world, this makes you a “seeker” who wants to test these updates
in advance before most Windows users get them.
Microsoft disclosed this in a recent blog post :
[Windows monthly security and quality updates overview](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/12/10/windows-monthly-security-and-quality-updates-overview/).

The Windows 10 telemetry will detect any problem caused by these updates
before they appear in the next B update, without any thank-you note for
unwittingly helping Microsoft out.

In other words, clicking the “Check for Updates” button qualifies you as
a beta tester for updates.

So, if you click “Check for Updates” in the third, fourth, or first week of a month,
before the next B update has been released, you’ll probably get a C or D update installed on your system. If you never click “Check for Updates”, you’ll stick with the better-tested B updates (tested by others than yourself).

So the solution is simple : Do not click “Check for Updates” before the B updates
have been released by Microsoft, and never after the second week of the month.

My personal advice would be to never use “Check for Updates”, because of the
risk of forcing the installation of updates that have not yet been
vetted for your computer mode. It's preferable to let Windows Update
decide which updates are now ready and tested for your computer and
installed software.