# Active Hours by registry: reboot required?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, updates

I am looking for a way to suppress Windows Updates while Autodesk installs and updates run, since Windows will walk all over other updates and force a reboot that jacks everything up.

I found [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-restart) which has me thinking I could use PowerShell to set ActiveHoursStart = Now-1 and ActiveHoursEnd = Now+10, then when my work is done set everything back to something reasonable, like active hours of 6AM to Midnight (architects work RIDICULOUS active hours). My question, before I go down this rabbit hole, is; are settings pushed to the registry immediately in force, or is this read at logon or something, so without a reboot I haven't solved the problem?

Comment: Setting your Active Hours takes effect immediately.  Which is the reason the answer to this duplicate question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10) works.  You are looking for the one with the batch script by the way[.](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10).  Since there isn't a better solution than the existing solution I flagged this question as a duplicate (this is a positive thing), your issue, will be linked to the duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \*disable\* automatic reboots in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10)

Comment: Ah, glad to hear it takes affect immediately. When I read the various posts I found, none seemed to answer that question. Plowing on!