# Suppress Windows Updates for current user

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I am trying to find a consistent way to disable Windows Update for a specific user, used to install Autodesk software, because ADSK stuff can trigger Windows updates and disrupt the ADSK install process. I only want to affect the specific user, and leave the regular users configured as they are, with their own Active Hours in Windows 10, etc.
I found [this](https://itstillworks.com/disable-windows-update-registry-5778869.html) that works for Windows 7, and looking at Windows Updates in Settings I see the change from user settings to Manager by System Admin and back. But, when I try the same thing in Windows 10, I don't see any change in settings. But that could be because Windows Updates in Windows 10 is just broken for me now, like their server is having issues or something. So, I am hoping someone can verify that this will indeed work as expected, and suppress Windows Updates only for the logged on user, in all builds of Windows 10 as well as Windows 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping all automatic updates Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10)[,](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a duplicate, as no where in that does it talk about this specific Current User registry based approach. Is that because the other thread is truly exhaustive and this approach does not work? Or is it possible this does work, and that is the answer I am looking for? Fingers crossed.

Comment: The duplicate is normally treated as the canonical question with regards to disabling Windows Update on Windows 10.  A question can be a duplicate if it has answers that are applicable to another question.  Your desire to only disable Windows Update with a single user doesn't make it unique enough.  I know [this](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1) question has answers that can be applied to specific users.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I am missing something. I don't see anything there that shows a way to disable WU for a single user, via the registry. That last option looks like it has potential, but it specifically uses HKLM not CU, and makes no reference to a user based option. As for not being unique enough, how can differentiating between a single user and globally shutting down updates on the machine NOT be unique enough? That seems like a pretty massive differentiation to my mind. Like, one solves a simple install problem and the other cripples the machine completely.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10/1208866#1208866) answer can be implemented for a single user.      It of course isn't exactly what you want, you will have to adapt the script, so the script is only ran for the specific user.

Comment: The link you are asking about only is appcliable to Windows 7.  Windows 10 changed how Windows Update works.  What worked for Windows 7 does not work for Windows 10.