# How to prevent windows 10 update while a specific exe is running

Tags: windows-10

I want to disable windows 10 automatic update feature when a specific program is running. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083525/prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-restarting-after-an-update-programmaticall) post however it is not what I wanted specifically. I also saw batch file scripts but they permanently disable updates which is also not suitable for me. Could you help me please?

Comment: I doubts there is a way to do what you want, but maybe someone here can figure a way.

Comment: I concur with the previous comment.

Comment: Do you have source to the application?  [The script that continuously updates the active hours, which disables Windows Updates, on any version of Windows can easily be added the source code of any application.](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10/1208866#1208866)

Comment: Perhaps a powershell script setup in task-scheduler to run every 1-5 minutes - when run, it detects the .exe you want to exempt, and if so makes sure update is disabled. If it doesn't detect it, it enabled updates again. Perhaps you could even set the trigger as the startup of the .exe ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to disable windows 10 automatic update feature when a specific
>   program is running. I checked this post however it is not what I
>   wanted specifically. I also saw batch file scripts but they
>   permanently disable updates which is also not suitable for me. Could
>   you help me please?

This can easily be performed.

> ```
> function RunTask {
>     $task = GetTask
>     if ($task)
>     {
>     $firefox = Get-Process firefox -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
>       if ($firefox) 
>       {
>         $task | Start-ScheduledTask
>         Write-Output "$TaskPath$TaskName executed"
>       }          
>     }
>     else {
>         Write-Output "$TaskPath$TaskName not found"
>     }
> }
> ```

The above functions comes from a GitHub project called [Win10ActiveHours](https://github.com/marcosbozzani/Win10ActiveHours), which runs a scheduled task, by running a scheduled task every 18 hours.  The task resets the active hours at 0600 to 1800.  While this does not prevent an update from being installed, it will prevent the automatic reboot, that normally would happen automatically.

**I provided a 4 line modification, that will detect if a process is running, and if the task will be allowed to run.**  While it is possible to disable to disable Windows Update, through a [PowerShell](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1) script, I do not actually suggest doing that.  You could in theory run the provided [function](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10/1313298#1313298), when the `Win10ActiveHours` scheduled task is run, but you would have to write your own code to enable Windows Updates if process is not detected.

You can also set the Windows Update deferment policy by making a modification to the appropriate registry key through PowerShell.

Source:

- [How to Correctly Check if a Process is running and Stop it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481811/how-to-correctly-check-if-a-process-is-running-and-stop-it)
- [How to *disable* automatic reboots in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10/1456571#1456571)

Comment: I checked the git link and I am trying to understand since I can not read script code, in your script, you assume your open program is firefox right? So as long as it is open , you say, go on continue to update but don't reboot. Right?