# Windows 10, automatically updates installation after a certain period of time

Tags: windows, windows-update, updates, group-policy

We want to give our users the opportunity to choose when to install updates. But we need to control the installation process.

If the user does not start installing updates within a week, the updates will be installed automatically. Additionally, the user should have one more week to make a decision about a restart.

Configure group policies “Configure Automatic Updates (Auto download and notify for install)” and “Specify deadlines for automatic updates and restarts” does not produce the desired result - updates are downloaded but not installed automatically.

There are no problems with restart.

How can we configure auto installation of updates after a certain period of time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stopping all automatic updates Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10)

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for reply! Unfortunately this does not solve the problem. We need to configure deadlines for automatic updates. Not disable updates at all.

Comment: If you need to deploy updates on a schedule you need to deploy your own [WSUS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/configmgr/sum/deploy-use/software-updates-maintenance) within your infrastructure and use the appropriate tools to do so.

Comment: What tools do you mean?
We have wsus. Windows 10 computers receive updates from it. Now we have GPO to automatically install updates every Friday.
But we would like to enable the user to determine the time for installing updates within a week on their own. If the user did not select the installation time, we would like for the updates to be automatically installed in a week.

Comment: I am referring to [Configuration Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/configmgr/sum/understand/software-updates-introduction).  I believe one tool is called Software Update, allows you to schedule when updates must be installed, either way your not going to be able to force an update with greater control over the process or a custom script that does something similar