# How to keep Edgehtml based Microsoft Edge after the next 13th april?

Tags: windows-update, microsoft-edge

I know it is no longer maintened, but I already have Google Chrome. [Microsoft is planning a security update for removing it](https://www.engadget.com/microsoft-edge-legacy-phase-out-232116614.html). How to blacklist such future update without disabling automatic Microsoft update?

Answer (score 2):

> How to blacklist such future update without disabling automatic Microsoft update?

Unless you are willing to disable Windows Updates entirely this cannot be done.
**The only way to achieve what you want would be to disable Windows Update entirely and not install any cumulative updates or feature updates.**  All feature upgrades in the future will not even contain Legacy Edge.  All future cumulative updates, after April 13th, 2021 would result in the removal of Legacy Edge and Chromium Edge would be installed.

**Unlike Internet Explorer 11, Microsoft has made it clear due to their specified timeline, that they do not intend to allow Legacy Edge to remain in operation after April 13th, 2021.**

> To replace this out of support application, we are announcing that the new Microsoft Edge will be available as part of the Windows 10 cumulative monthly security update—otherwise referred to as the Update Tuesday (or “B”) release—on April 13, 2021. When you apply this update to your devices, the out of support Microsoft Edge Legacy desktop application will be removed and the new Microsoft Edge will be installed. The new Microsoft Edge offers built-in security and our best interoperability with the Microsoft security ecosystem, all while being more secure than Chrome for businesses on Windows 10.

By including Chromium Edge in a cumulative update it means that all cumulative updates in the future will also include it.  Only `Windows 10 version 1803` through `Windows 10 version 2004` will be affected by the cumulative update in April 2021.  Windows 10 version 20H2 will simply uninstall Legacy Edge on April 2021.  **I mention that because, in theory, you could just run an earlier version of Windows 10.  That will mean you are running an unsupported version of Windows 10, and I don't actually recommend that solution.**

> Because Windows 10, 20H2 already uses the new Microsoft Edge as its default browser, it will not be reinstalled; only Microsoft Edge Legacy will be removed.

How you decide to block the update in April 2021 is entirely up to you.  However, eventually, you will have to install a cumulative update or install a feature update and Legacy Edge will be uninstalled.

Microsoft has indicated that legacy applications that require EdgeHTML will continue to work for the time being.

> Will this affect other apps that use EdgeHTML?
> EdgeHTML—the rendering engine for Microsoft Edge Legacy—will continue to be supported. To develop apps for the new Microsoft Edge, use [WebView2](https://docs.microsoft.com/microsoft-edge/webview2/), the Chromium-based version of Microsoft’s WebView.

Relevant Sources:

- [Stopping all automatic updates Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How to Give Yourself More Time to Uninstall Windows 10 Updates](https://www.howtogeek.com/362090/how-to-give-yourself-more-time-to-uninstall-windows-10-updates/)