# PC is updating continuously for half an hour on every startup

Tags: windows-update, dell-inspiron, automatic-update

I have Windows 10 on my home laptop. I start it only 2 days a week, because I usually use my tablet. Every time I start it, Windows, Dell, or something else is updating, disk or cpu usage being 100%, making the laptop unusable for about half an hour. Is there any way to fix this, or should I keep the laptop on 24x7, even if I use it only a few hours a week?

Comment: Windows 10 allows you to set activity hours allowing it to schedule when you are not using the update.  [You can fool the system by continuously updating this time allowing you to update Windows manually on your own time.](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10).  If you kept the laptop on you ironically wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: No, this is not normal if you are booting it a couple of times a week.  I only boot several of my machines on that schedule and have no such issue.  Windows only updates once a month unless something REALLY BAD comes along.. My dell *crap* only updates every once in a while.  Even then.. my machine is still usable while it is updating.. certainly not at 100%.  Are you using a non-microsoft antivirus?  If so, try removing it for defender and see if the problem goes away.  Updates should not get 100% of the CPU.

Comment: I don't have any antivirus, except what Windows has by default. It's for about 25 minutes 100% disk, and for about 5 minutes 100% cpu.