# Windows 10 Update, sth. like "active days"

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, scheduled-tasks

I would like to deny Windows Updates on the weekends, but not during nights for working days, since we run production tests over weekends:

- In the documentation for Windows Updates, I can find information about specifying *active hours* only, but that option does not help very much:

  - [Manage device restarts after updates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-restart)
  - [Manage updates in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/manage-updates-in-windows-643e9ea7-3cf6-7da6-a25c-95d4f7f099fe)

Do you know some workaround or a third party tool which allows to deny updates on certain days or at least forbid restarts?

Comment: If there's not an option or Group Policy to set this, the easiest way may be to implement time-based firewall rules to block traffic to the Windows Update Servers through Task scheduler _(run a basic script to create the Windows firewall rules at a specific time, then a separate task to run a basic script at a different time to remove the rules)_, or the same could be done on the router's firewall through `iptables`/it's applicable firewall _(this may be more efficient depending on the number of machines this needs to be applied to)_

Comment: Sounds promising. However, I would like to second that with my colleagues.

Comment: So this is an obvious duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-all-automatic-updates-windows-10) all you would have to do is modify the script so it only works on certain days.  You probably would have to use PowerShell instead of Bash, that conversion is trivial. So you don’t need to prevent the updates themselves, your just attempting to prevent the automatic reboots on the weekend, [this](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10) continuously changes the activity hours every 6 hours.

Comment: However, this really is solve by good group policy enforcement, and pushing updates on your own schedule with WSUS and the proper tools provided by Microsoft