# How to make Windows Update not to use all the internet band?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

Is there a way to make Windows Updates ***not ot use up*** all the internet band?

I use Windows 8.1 Home Edition (64 bits).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit bandwidth used by Windows Update](http://superuser.com/q/1039229/10259), [How do I stop Windows Operating System from using up my bandwidth quota?](http://superuser.com/q/463020/10259) and/or [How can I throttle the bandwidth consumed by Windows Automatic Updates?](http://superuser.com/q/84723/10259)

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do it out of box in the Home Edition. You could install a 3. Party Application like Netlimiter(https://www.netlimiter.com/). I can't guarantee that this will work.

If you would have the pro or enterprise Version you could set it in the local group policys [LCP > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Network >  Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS)]